# Java 8 Stream, getting head and tail

Tags: java, scala, java-8, java-stream, sieve

Java 8 introduced a [Stream](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) class that resembles Scala's [Stream](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html), a powerful lazy construct using which it is possible to do something like this very concisely:

```scala
def from(n: Int): Stream[Int] = n #:: from(n+1)

def sieve(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = {
  s.head #:: sieve(s.tail filter (_ % s.head != 0))
}

val primes = sieve(from(2))

primes takeWhile(_ < 1000) print  // prints all primes less than 1000
```

I wondered if it is possible to do this in Java 8, so I wrote something like this:

```java
IntStream from(int n) {
    return IntStream.iterate(n, m -> m + 1);
}

IntStream sieve(IntStream s) {
    int head = s.findFirst().getAsInt();
    return IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(head), sieve(s.skip(1).filter(n -> n % head != 0)));
}

IntStream primes = sieve(from(2));
```

Fairly simple, but it produces `java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed` because both `findFirst()` and `skip()` are terminal operations on `Stream` which can be done only once.

I don't really have to use up the stream twice since all I need is the first number in the stream and the rest as another stream, i.e. equivalent of Scala's `Stream.head` and `Stream.tail`. Is there a method in Java 8 `Stream` that I can use to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to operate over the stream that way, the best you'll be able to do is probably to wrap its `iterator()`.  (To say nothing of the fact that your implementation isn't actually a proper prime sieve; see e.g. [this paper](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf).)

Comment: I have tried extracting the first number and reconstructing another stream like `IntStream.generate(() -> it.next())`, but the iterator's `hasNext()` works eagerly and leads to an infinite recursion.

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work.  Really, this isn't going to work cleanly with `Stream`s at all.

Comment: See this [blog post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/lazy-sequences-implementation) for an explanation on how to build a lazy sequence by yourself in Java.

Comment: I [programmed this recently](https://gist.github.com/edalorzo/5135612) with JDK8, but I built my own stream, since I do not think JDK 8 streams are exactly the same thing as the scala's lazy streams.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even if you hadn’t the problem that you can’t split an `IntStream`, you code didn’t work because you are invoking your `sieve` method recursively instead of lazily. So you had an infinity recursion before you could query your resulting stream for the first value.

Splitting an `IntStream s` into a head and a tail `IntStream` (which has not yet consumed) is possible:

```
PrimitiveIterator.OfInt it = s.iterator();
int head = it.nextInt();
IntStream tail = IntStream.generate(it::next).filter(i -> i % head != 0);
```

At this place you need a construct of invoking `sieve` on the tail lazily. `Stream` does not provide that; `concat` expects existing stream instances as arguments and you can’t construct a stream invoking `sieve` lazily with a lambda expression as lazy creation works with mutable state only which lambda expressions do not support. If you don’t have a library implementation hiding the mutable state you have to use a mutable object. But once you accept the requirement of mutable state, the solution can be even easier than your first approach:

```
IntStream primes = from(2).filter(i -> p.test(i)).peek(i -> p = p.and(v -> v % i != 0));

IntPredicate p = x -> true;

IntStream from(int n)
{
  return IntStream.iterate(n, m -> m + 1);
}
```

This will recursively create a filter but in the end it doesn’t matter whether you create a tree of `IntPredicate`s or a tree of `IntStream`s (like with your `IntStream.concat` approach if it did work). If you don’t like the mutable instance field for the filter you can hide it in an inner class (but not in a lambda expression…).

Comment: I don't think this works, you can't refer to non-final variables inside lambda expressions.

Comment: @djjeck: if you refer to the second solution, these are *fields*, not local variables, and can be modified. The variables of the first example are *effectively final*. And both examples are tested and proven.

Comment: You're right, that works (and you actually mention it in the answer). Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

My [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/) library has now [`headTail()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#headTail-java.util.function.BiFunction-) operation which solves the problem:

```
public static StreamEx<Integer> sieve(StreamEx<Integer> input) {
    return input.headTail((head, tail) -> 
        sieve(tail.filter(n -> n % head != 0)).prepend(head));
}
```

The `headTail` method takes a `BiFunction` which will be executed at most once during the stream terminal operation execution. So this implementation is lazy: it does not compute anything until traversal starts and computes only as much prime numbers as requested. The `BiFunction` receives a first stream element `head` and the stream of the rest elements `tail` and can modify the `tail` in any way it wants. You may use it with predefined input:

```
sieve(IntStreamEx.range(2, 1000).boxed()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

But infinite stream work as well

```
sieve(StreamEx.iterate(2, x -> x+1)).takeWhile(x -> x < 1000)
     .forEach(System.out::println);
// Not the primes till 1000, but 1000 first primes
sieve(StreamEx.iterate(2, x -> x+1)).limit(1000).forEach(System.out::println);
```

There's also alternative solution using `headTail` and predicate concatenation:

```
public static StreamEx<Integer> sieve(StreamEx<Integer> input, IntPredicate isPrime) {
    return input.headTail((head, tail) -> isPrime.test(head) 
            ? sieve(tail, isPrime.and(n -> n % head != 0)).prepend(head)
            : sieve(tail, isPrime));
}

sieve(StreamEx.iterate(2, x -> x+1), i -> true).limit(1000).forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

It interesting to compare recursive solutions: how many primes they capable to generate.

**@John McClean solution (`StreamUtils`)**

John McClean solutions are not lazy: you cannot feed them with infinite stream. So I just found by trial-and-error the maximal allowed upper bound (`17793`) (after that StackOverflowError occurs):

```
public void sieveTest(){
    sieve(IntStream.range(2, 17793).boxed()).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**@John McClean solution (`Streamable`)**

```
public void sieveTest2(){
    sieve(Streamable.range(2, 39990)).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Increasing upper limit above `39990` results in StackOverflowError.

**@frhack solution (`LazySeq`)**

```
LazySeq<Integer> ints = integers(2);
LazySeq primes = sieve(ints); // sieve method from @frhack answer
primes.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p));
```

Result: stuck after prime number = `53327` with enormous heap allocation and garbage collection taking more than 90%. It took several minutes to advance from 53323 to 53327, so waiting more seems impractical.

**@vidi solution**

```
Prime.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Result: StackOverflowError after prime number = `134417`.

**My solution (StreamEx)**

```
sieve(StreamEx.iterate(2, x -> x+1)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Result: StackOverflowError after prime number = `236167`.

**@frhack solution (`rxjava`)**

```
Observable<Integer> primes = Observable.from(()->primesStream.iterator());
primes.forEach((x) -> System.out.println(x.toString()));
```

Result: StackOverflowError after prime number = `367663`.

**@Holger solution**

```
IntStream primes=from(2).filter(i->p.test(i)).peek(i->p=p.and(v->v%i!=0));
primes.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Result: StackOverflowError after prime number = `368089`.

**My solution (StreamEx with predicate concatenation)**

```
sieve(StreamEx.iterate(2, x -> x+1), i -> true).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Result: StackOverflowError after prime number = `368287`.

---

So three solutions involving predicate concatenation win, because each new condition adds only 2 more stack frames. I think, the difference between them is marginal and should not be considered to define a winner. However I like my first StreamEx solution more as it more similar to Scala code.

Comment: Could you please add timing comparison of respective solutions? Since they **all** involve predicate contatenation (just more or less explicit) and the **modulo** operation, they might score equally, though.

Comment: Hey man, great work with this library. We use it fairly extensively. The MoreCollectors.flatMapping was really useful, now it is in Java 9. A lot of things you did here could actually be candidates to the main JDK baseline 10+

Answer (score 3):

The solution below does not do state mutations, except for the head/tail deconstruction of the stream.

The lazyness is obtained using IntStream.iterate. The class Prime is used to keep the generator state

```
    import java.util.PrimitiveIterator;
    import java.util.stream.IntStream;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;

    public class Prime {
        private final IntStream candidates;
        private final int current;

        private Prime(int current, IntStream candidates)
        {
            this.current = current;
            this.candidates = candidates;
        }

        private Prime next()
        {
            PrimitiveIterator.OfInt it = candidates.filter(n -> n % current != 0).iterator();

            int head = it.next();
            IntStream tail = IntStream.generate(it::next);

            return new Prime(head, tail);
        }

        public static Stream<Integer> stream() {
            IntStream possiblePrimes = IntStream.iterate(3, i -> i + 1);

            return Stream.iterate(new Prime(2, possiblePrimes), Prime::next)
                         .map(p -> p.current);
        }
    }
```

The usage would be this:

```
Stream<Integer> first10Primes = Prime.stream().limit(10)
```

Comment: It would be great to avoid the **modulo** operation and take advantage of the additive nature of the sieve. Something along the lines of `IntStream impossiblePrimes = IntStream.iterate(head * head, i -> i + 2 * head);`. But sure, it's more primes-related than head/tail-related.

Answer (score 2):

You can essentially implement it like this:

```
static <T> Tuple2<Optional<T>, Seq<T>> splitAtHead(Stream<T> stream) {
    Iterator<T> it = stream.iterator();
    return tuple(it.hasNext() ? Optional.of(it.next()) : Optional.empty(), seq(it));
}
```

In the above example, `Tuple2` and `Seq` are types borrowed from [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL), a library that we developed for [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) integration tests. If you don't want any additional dependencies, you might as well implement them yourself:

```
class Tuple2<T1, T2> {
    final T1 v1;
    final T2 v2;

    Tuple2(T1 v1, T2 v2) {
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.v2 = v2;
    }

    static <T1, T2> Tuple2<T1, T2> tuple(T1 v1, T2 v2) {
        return new Tuple<>(v1, v2);
    }
}

static <T> Tuple2<Optional<T>, Stream<T>> splitAtHead(Stream<T> stream) {
    Iterator<T> it = stream.iterator();
    return tuple(
        it.hasNext() ? Optional.of(it.next()) : Optional.empty,
        StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
            it, Spliterator.ORDERED
        ), false)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using 3rd party libraries [cyclops-streams](https://github.com/aol/cyclops/tree/master/cyclops-streams), I library I wrote has a number of potential solutions.

The [StreamUtils](http://static.javadoc.io/com.aol.cyclops/cyclops-streams/7.1.0/com/aol/cyclops/streams/StreamUtils.html) class has large number of static methods for working directly with `java.util.stream.Streams` including `headAndTail`.

```
HeadAndTail<Integer> headAndTail = StreamUtils.headAndTail(Stream.of(1,2,3,4));
int head = headAndTail.head(); //1
Stream<Integer> tail = headAndTail.tail(); //Stream[2,3,4]
```

The [Streamable](http://static.javadoc.io/com.aol.cyclops/cyclops-sequence-api/7.1.0/com/aol/cyclops/sequence/streamable/Streamable.html) class represents a replayable `Stream` and works by building a lazy, caching intermediate data-structure. Because it is caching and repayable - head and tail can be implemented directly and separately.

```
Streamable<Integer> replayable=  Streamable.fromStream(Stream.of(1,2,3,4));
int head = repayable.head(); //1
Stream<Integer> tail = replayable.tail(); //Stream[2,3,4]
```

[cyclops-streams](https://github.com/aol/cyclops/tree/master/cyclops-streams) also provides a sequential `Stream` extension that in turn extends [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) and has both `Tuple` based (from jOOλ)  and domain object (HeadAndTail) solutions for head and tail extraction.

```
SequenceM.of(1,2,3,4)
         .splitAtHead(); //Tuple[1,SequenceM[2,3,4]

SequenceM.of(1,2,3,4)
         .headAndTail();
```

Update per Tagir's request -> A Java version of the Scala sieve using `SequenceM`

```
public void sieveTest(){
    sieve(SequenceM.range(2, 1_000)).forEach(System.out::println);
}

SequenceM<Integer> sieve(SequenceM<Integer> s){

    return s.headAndTailOptional().map(ht ->SequenceM.of(ht.head())
                            .appendStream(sieve(ht.tail().filter(n -> n % ht.head() != 0))))
                    .orElse(SequenceM.of());
}
```

And another version via `Streamable`

```
public void sieveTest2(){
    sieve(Streamable.range(2, 1_000)).forEach(System.out::println);
}

Streamable<Integer> sieve(Streamable<Integer> s){

    return s.size()==0? Streamable.of() : Streamable.of(s.head())
                                                    .appendStreamable(sieve(s.tail()
                                                                    .filter(n -> n % s.head() != 0)));
}
```

Note - neither `Streamable` of `SequenceM` have an Empty implementation - hence the size check for `Streamable` and the use of `headAndTailOptional`.

Finally a version using plain `java.util.stream.Stream`

```
import static com.aol.cyclops.streams.StreamUtils.headAndTailOptional;

public void sieveTest(){
    sieve(IntStream.range(2, 1_000).boxed()).forEach(System.out::println);
}

Stream<Integer> sieve(Stream<Integer> s){

    return headAndTailOptional(s).map(ht ->Stream.concat(Stream.of(ht.head())
                            ,sieve(ht.tail().filter(n -> n % ht.head() != 0))))
                    .orElse(Stream.of());
}
```

Another update - a lazy iterative based on @Holger's version using objects rather than primitives (note a primitive version is also possible)

```
  final Mutable<Predicate<Integer>> predicate = Mutable.of(x->true);
  SequenceM.iterate(2, n->n+1)
           .filter(i->predicate.get().test(i))
           .peek(i->predicate.mutate(p-> p.and(v -> v%i!=0)))
           .limit(100000)
           .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the full solution of primes problem using your libraries.

Comment: Teammate going to play around with implementing a sieve of Eratosthenes with Streamable / SequenceM - will keep you posted.

Comment: `final List<Integer> prime = new ArrayList<>();
  SequenceM<Integer> primeNumbers = SequenceM.generate(() ->
  {
   synchronized (prime) {
    if (prime.isEmpty()) {
     prime.add(2);
    } else {
     int last = prime.get(prime.size() - 1);
     do {
      int candidate = last;
      if (!prime.stream().parallel().anyMatch(c -> (candidate) % c == 0)) {
       prime.add(candidate);
       break;
      }
      last++;
     } while (true);
    }
    return prime.get(prime.size() - 1);
   }
  });`

Comment: Looks that both solutions are not lazy though. Try `sieve(Stream.iterate(2, x -> x+1)).limit(1000)` as the source, for example.

Comment: Yes, the head is evaluated immediately each time, the tail is processed lazily. It's a pretty trivial modification to make the head() method in HeadAndTail evaluate lazily however and one that we will add soon.

Comment: You probably mean the solution provided isn't Lazy? Yes that's true, I'll update with a Lazy version (the question did specify a pretty low limit originally though).

Answer (score 1):

There are many interesting suggestions provided here, but if someone needs a solution without dependencies to third party libraries I came up with this:

```
    import java.util.AbstractMap;
    import java.util.Optional;
    import java.util.Spliterators;
    import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

    /**
     * Splits a stream in the head element and a tail stream.
     * Parallel streams are not supported.
     * 
     * @param stream Stream to split.
     * @param <T> Type of the input stream.
     * @return A map entry where {@link Map.Entry#getKey()} contains an
     *    optional with the first element (head) of the original stream
     *    and {@link Map.Entry#getValue()} the tail of the original stream.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException for parallel streams.
     */
    public static <T> Map.Entry<Optional<T>, Stream<T>> headAndTail(final Stream<T> stream) {
        if (stream.isParallel()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("parallel streams are not supported");
        }
        final Iterator<T> iterator = stream.iterator();
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(
                iterator.hasNext() ? Optional.of(iterator.next()) : Optional.empty(),
                StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0), false)
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get head and tail you need a Lazy Stream implementation. Java 8 stream or RxJava are not suitable.

You can use for example [LazySeq](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/LazySeq) as follows.

> Lazy sequence is always traversed from the beginning using very cheap
>   first/rest decomposition (head() and tail())
>
> LazySeq implements java.util.List interface, thus can be used in
>   variety of places. Moreover it also implements Java 8 enhancements to
>   collections, namely streams and collectors

---

```
package com.company;

import com.nurkiewicz.lazyseq.LazySeq;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LazySeq<Integer> ints = integers(2);
        LazySeq primes = sieve(ints);
        primes.take(10).forEach(p -> System.out.println(p));

    }

    private static LazySeq<Integer> sieve(LazySeq<Integer> s) {
        return LazySeq.cons(s.head(), () -> sieve(s.filter(x -> x % s.head() != 0)));
    }

    private static LazySeq<Integer> integers(int from) {
        return LazySeq.cons(from, () -> integers(from + 1));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another recipe using the way suggested by Holger.
It use RxJava just to add the possibility to use the take(int) method and many others.

```
package com.company;

import rx.Observable;

import java.util.function.IntPredicate;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final IntPredicate[] p={(x)->true};
        IntStream primesStream=IntStream.iterate(2,n->n+1).filter(i -> p[0].test(i)).peek(i->p[0]=p[0].and(v->v%i!=0)   );

        Observable primes = Observable.from(()->primesStream.iterator());

        primes.take(10).forEach((x) -> System.out.println(x.toString()));


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with parallel streams as well:

```java
public static <T> Map.Entry<Optional<T>, Stream<T>> headAndTail(final Stream<T> stream) {
    final AtomicReference<Optional<T>> head = new AtomicReference<>(Optional.empty());
    final var spliterator = stream.spliterator();
    spliterator.tryAdvance(x -> head.set(Optional.of(x)));
    return Map.entry(head.get(), StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, stream.isParallel()));
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to get head of a stream, just:

```
IntStream.range(1, 5).first();
```

If you want to get tail of a stream, just:

```
IntStream.range(1, 5).skip(1);
```

If you want to get both head and tail of a stream, just:

```
IntStream s = IntStream.range(1, 5);
int head = s.head();
IntStream tail = s.tail();
```

If you want to find the prime, just:

```
LongStream.range(2, n)
   .filter(i -> LongStream.range(2, (long) Math.sqrt(i) + 1).noneMatch(j -> i % j == 0))
   .forEach(N::println);
```

If you want to know more, go to get [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

Declaration： I'm the developer of abacus-common.