# Limit a stream by a predicate

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there a Java 8 stream operation that limits a (potentially infinite) `Stream` until the first element fails to match a predicate?

In Java 9 we can use `takeWhile` as in the example below to print all the numbers less than 10.

```
IntStream
    .iterate(1, n -> n + 1)
    .takeWhile(n -> n < 10)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

As there is no such operation in Java 8, what's the best way of implementing it in a general way?

Comment: Possibly useful information at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19803058/248082

Comment: Related: [Equivalent of Scala dropWhile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25569836)

Comment: I am wondering how the architects could ever get through the "what can we actually _use_ this for" without running into this usecase.  As of Java 8 Streams are only actually helpful for existing datastructures :-/

Comment: See also [How to short-circuit a reduce() operation on a Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495069/how-to-short-circuit-a-reduce-operation-on-a-stream)

Comment: With Java 9, it would be easier to write
`IntStream.iterate(1, n->n<10, n->n+1).forEach(System.out::print);`

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Operations `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` have been added to JDK 9. Your example code

```
IntStream
    .iterate(1, n -> n + 1)
    .takeWhile(n -> n < 10)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

will behave exactly as you expect it to when compiled and run under JDK 9.

JDK 9 has been released. It is available for download here: [JDK 9 Releases](http://jdk.java.net/9/).

Comment: Direct link to the preview docs for JDK9 Stream, with `takeWhile`/`dropWhile`: http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Comment: Is there any reason why they're called `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` rather than `limitWhile` and `skipWhile`, for consistency with existing API?

Comment: @LukasEder `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` are pretty widespread, occurring in Scala, Python, Groovy, Ruby, Haskell, and Clojure. The asymmetry with `skip` and `limit` is unfortunate. Maybe `skip` and `limit` ought to have been called `drop` and `take`, but those aren't as intuitive unless you're already familiar with Haskell.

Comment: @StuartMarks: I understand that `dropXXX` and `takeXXX` are more popular terms but I can personally live with the more SQL-esque `limitXXX` and `skipXXX`. I find this new asymmetry much more confusing than the individual choice of terms... :) (btw: Scala also has `drop(int)` and `take(int)`)

Comment: yeah let me just upgrade to Jdk 9 in production. Many devs are still on Jdk8, such a feature should have been included with Streams from the start.

Comment: `IntStream .iterate(1, n -> n + 1) .takeWhile(n -> n < 10)` can be simplified to `IntStream .iterate(1, n -> n < 10, n -> n + 1)`

Comment: @Holger it's preference, but I prefer the slightly more verbose one as it is easier to understand what is going on.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano in this case it’s understandable as `iterate(1, n -> n < 10, n -> n + 1)` directly corresponds to `for(int n = 1; n < 10; n = n + 1)`

Answer (score 85):

Such an operation ought to be *possible* with a Java 8 `Stream`, but it can't necessarily be done efficiently -- for example, you can't necessarily parallelize such an operation, as you have to look at elements in order.

The API doesn't provide an easy way to do it, but what's probably the simplest way is to take `Stream.iterator()`, wrap the [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html) to have a "take-while" implementation, and then go back to a `Spliterator` and then a `Stream`.  Or -- maybe -- wrap the [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Spliterator.html), though it can't really be split anymore in this implementation.

Here's an untested implementation of `takeWhile` on a `Spliterator`:

```
static <T> Spliterator<T> takeWhile(
    Spliterator<T> splitr, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
  return new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(splitr.estimateSize(), 0) {
    boolean stillGoing = true;
    @Override public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
      if (stillGoing) {
        boolean hadNext = splitr.tryAdvance(elem -> {
          if (predicate.test(elem)) {
            consumer.accept(elem);
          } else {
            stillGoing = false;
          }
        });
        return hadNext && stillGoing;
      }
      return false;
    }
  };
}

static <T> Stream<T> takeWhile(Stream<T> stream, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
   return StreamSupport.stream(takeWhile(stream.spliterator(), predicate), false);
}
```

Comment: In theory, parallelizing takeWhile with a stateless predicate is easy. Evaluate the condition in parallel batches (assuming the predicate doesn't throw or have a side-effect if executed a few extra times). The problem is doing it in the context of recursive decomposition (fork/join framework) that Streams use. Really, it's Streams that are horribly inefficient.

Comment: Streams would have been a lot better if they weren't so preoccupied with automagical parallelism. Parallelism is needed in only a tiny fraction of places where Streams can be used. Besides,  if Oracle cared so much about perfoance,  they could have made the JVM JIT autovectorize,  and gotten a much bigger performamce boost, without bothering the developers. Now that is automagical parallelism done right.

Comment: You should update this answer now that Java 9 is released.

Comment: No, @Radiodef. The question asks specifically for a Java 8 solution.

Answer (score 58):

`allMatch()` is a short-circuiting function, so you can use it to stop processing. The main disadvantage is that you have to do your test twice: once to see if you should process it, and again to see whether to keep going.

```
IntStream
    .iterate(1, n -> n + 1)
    .peek(n->{if (n<10) System.out.println(n);})
    .allMatch(n->n < 10);
```

Comment: This seemed unintuitive to me at first (given the method name), but the [docs confirm](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) that `Stream.allMatch()` is a [short-circuiting operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps). So this will complete even on an infinite stream like `IntStream.iterate()`. Of course, in retrospect, this is a sensible optimization.

Comment: This is neat, but I don't think it communicates very well that its intent is the body of the `peek`.  If I encountered it next month, I would take a minute to wonder why the programmer before me checked if `allMatch` and then ignored the answer.

Comment: The disadvantage of this solution is that it returns a boolean so you cannot collect the results of the stream as you normally would.

Answer (score 37):

As a follow-up to [@StuartMarks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32304570/4856258). My [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library has the [`takeWhile`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/IntStreamEx.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.IntPredicate-) operation which is compatible with current JDK-9 implementation. When running under JDK-9 it will just delegate to the JDK implementation (via `MethodHandle.invokeExact` which is really fast). When running under JDK-8, the "polyfill" implementation will be used. So using my library the problem can be solved like this:

```
IntStreamEx.iterate(1, n -> n + 1)
           .takeWhile(n -> n < 10)
           .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Why have you not implemented it for the StreamEx class?

Comment: @Someguy I did implement it.

Answer (score 14):

`takeWhile` is one of the functions provided by the [protonpack library](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack).

```
Stream<Integer> infiniteInts = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1);
Stream<Integer> finiteInts = StreamUtils.takeWhile(infiniteInts, i -> i < 10);

assertThat(finiteInts.collect(Collectors.toList()),
           hasSize(10));
```

Answer (score 12):

**Update: Java 9 `Stream` now comes with a [takeWhile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) method.**

No needs for hacks or other solutions. Just use that!

---

I am sure this can be greatly improved upon: 
(someone could make it thread-safe maybe)

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.iterate(0, n -> n + 1);

TakeWhile.stream(stream, n -> n < 10000)
         .forEach(n -> System.out.print((n == 0 ? "" + n : "," + n)));
```

### A hack for sure... Not elegant - but it works ~:D

```
class TakeWhile<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private final Iterator<T> iterator;
    private final Predicate<T> predicate;
    private volatile T next;
    private volatile boolean keepGoing = true;

    public TakeWhile(Stream<T> s, Predicate<T> p) {
        this.iterator = s.iterator();
        this.predicate = p;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (!keepGoing) {
            return false;
        }
        if (next != null) {
            return true;
        }
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            next = iterator.next();
            keepGoing = predicate.test(next);
            if (!keepGoing) {
                next = null;
            }
        }
        return next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        if (next == null) {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Sorry. Nothing for you.");
            }
        }
        T temp = next;
        next = null;
        return temp;
    }

    public static <T> Stream<T> stream(Stream<T> s, Predicate<T> p) {
        TakeWhile tw = new TakeWhile(s, p);
        Spliterator split = Spliterators.spliterator(tw, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED);
        return StreamSupport.stream(split, false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use java8 + [rxjava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava).

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import rx.Observable;


// Example 1)
IntStream intStream  = IntStream.iterate(1, n -> n + 1);
Observable.from(() -> intStream.iterator())
    .takeWhile(n ->
          {
                System.out.println(n);
                return n < 10;
          }
    ).subscribe() ;


// Example 2
IntStream intStream  = IntStream.iterate(1, n -> n + 1);
Observable.from(() -> intStream.iterator())
    .takeWhile(n -> n < 10)
    .forEach( n -> System.out.println(n));
```

Answer (score 7):

Actually there are 2 ways to do it in Java 8 without any extra libraries or using Java 9.

If you want to print numbers from 2 to 20 on the console you can do this:

```
IntStream.iterate(2, (i) -> i + 2).peek(System.out::println).allMatch(i -> i < 20);
```

or

```
IntStream.iterate(2, (i) -> i + 2).peek(System.out::println).anyMatch(i -> i >= 20);
```

The output is in both cases:

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

No one mentioned *anyMatch* yet. This is the reason for this post.

Answer (score 6):

This is the source copied from JDK 9 java.util.stream.Stream.takeWhile(Predicate). A little difference in order to work with JDK 8.

```
static <T> Stream<T> takeWhile(Stream<T> stream, Predicate<? super T> p) {
    class Taking extends Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T> implements Consumer<T> {
        private static final int CANCEL_CHECK_COUNT = 63;
        private final Spliterator<T> s;
        private int count;
        private T t;
        private final AtomicBoolean cancel = new AtomicBoolean();
        private boolean takeOrDrop = true;

        Taking(Spliterator<T> s) {
            super(s.estimateSize(), s.characteristics() & ~(Spliterator.SIZED | Spliterator.SUBSIZED));
            this.s = s;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            boolean test = true;
            if (takeOrDrop &&               // If can take
                    (count != 0 || !cancel.get()) && // and if not cancelled
                    s.tryAdvance(this) &&   // and if advanced one element
                    (test = p.test(t))) {   // and test on element passes
                action.accept(t);           // then accept element
                return true;
            } else {
                // Taking is finished
                takeOrDrop = false;
                // Cancel all further traversal and splitting operations
                // only if test of element failed (short-circuited)
                if (!test)
                    cancel.set(true);
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Comparator<? super T> getComparator() {
            return s.getComparator();
        }

        @Override
        public void accept(T t) {
            count = (count + 1) & CANCEL_CHECK_COUNT;
            this.t = t;
        }

        @Override
        public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return StreamSupport.stream(new Taking(stream.spliterator()), stream.isParallel()).onClose(stream::close);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version done on ints - as asked in the question.

Usage:

```
StreamUtil.takeWhile(IntStream.iterate(1, n -> n + 1), n -> n < 10);
```

Here's code for StreamUtil:

```
import java.util.PrimitiveIterator;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.function.IntConsumer;
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class StreamUtil
{
    public static IntStream takeWhile(IntStream stream, IntPredicate predicate)
    {
        return StreamSupport.intStream(new PredicateIntSpliterator(stream, predicate), false);
    }

    private static class PredicateIntSpliterator extends Spliterators.AbstractIntSpliterator
    {
        private final PrimitiveIterator.OfInt iterator;
        private final IntPredicate predicate;

        public PredicateIntSpliterator(IntStream stream, IntPredicate predicate)
        {
            super(Long.MAX_VALUE, IMMUTABLE);
            this.iterator = stream.iterator();
            this.predicate = predicate;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(IntConsumer action)
        {
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                int value = iterator.nextInt();
                if (predicate.test(value)) {
                    action.accept(value);
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to get library [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common). It provides the exact API you want and more:

```
IntStream.iterate(1, n -> n + 1).takeWhile(n -> n < 10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Declaration： I'm the developer of AbacusUtil.

Answer (score 1):

```
    IntStream.iterate(1, n -> n + 1)
    .peek(System.out::println) //it will be executed 9 times
    .filter(n->n>=9)
    .findAny();
```

instead of peak you can use mapToObj to return final object or message

```
    IntStream.iterate(1, n -> n + 1)
    .mapToObj(n->{   //it will be executed 9 times
            if(n<9)
                return "";
            return "Loop repeats " + n + " times";});
    .filter(message->!message.isEmpty())
    .findAny()
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, if that works consistently

Answer (score 0):

You can't abort a stream except by a short-circuiting terminal operation, which would leave some stream values unprocessed regardless of their value. But if you just want to avoid operations on a stream you can add a transform and filter to the stream:

```
import java.util.Objects;

class ThingProcessor
{
    static Thing returnNullOnCondition(Thing thing)
    {    return( (*** is condition met ***)? null : thing);    }

    void processThings(Collection<Thing> thingsCollection)
    {
        thingsCollection.stream()
        *** regular stream processing ***
        .map(ThingProcessor::returnNullOnCondition)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        *** continue stream processing ***
    }
} // class ThingProcessor
```

That transforms the stream of things to nulls when the things meet some condition, then filters out nulls.  If you're willing to indulge in side effects, you could set the condition value to true once some thing is encountered, so all subsequent things are filtered out regardless of their value. But even if not you can save a lot of (if not quite all) processing by filtering values out of the stream that you don't want to process.

Comment: It's lame that some anonymous rater downrated my answer without saying why. So neither I nor any other reader knows what's wrong with my answer. In the absence of their justification I'll consider their criticism invalid, and my answer as posted to be correct.

Comment: You answer does not solve the OPs problem, which is dealing with infinite streams. It also seems to needlessly complicate things as you can write the condition in the filter() call itself, without needing map().
The question already has an example code, just try to apply your answer to that code and you will see the program will loop forever.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was having a similar requirement -- invoke the web-service, if it fails, retry it 3 times. If it fails even after these many trials, send an email notification. After googling a lot, `anyMatch()` came as a saviour. My sample code as follows. In the following example, if **webServiceCall** method returns true in the first iteration itself, stream does not iterate further as we have called `anyMatch()`. I believe, this is what you are looking for.

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import io.netty.util.internal.ThreadLocalRandom;

class TrialStreamMatch {

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    if(!IntStream.range(1,3).anyMatch(integ -> webServiceCall(integ))){
         //Code for sending email notifications
    }
}

public static boolean webServiceCall(int i){
    //For time being, I have written a code for generating boolean randomly
    //This whole piece needs to be replaced by actual web-service client code
    boolean bool = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean();
    System.out.println("Iteration index :: "+i+" bool :: "+bool);

    //Return success status -- true or false
    return bool;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact amount of repititions that will be performed, you can do

```
IntStream
          .iterate(1, n -> n + 1)
          .limit(10)
          .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score -2):

If you have different problem, different solution may be needed but for your current problem, I would simply go with:

```
IntStream
    .iterate(1, n -> n + 1)
    .limit(10)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score -2):

Might be a bit off topic but this is what we have for `List<T>` rather than `Stream<T>`.

First you need to have a `take` util method. This methods takes first `n` elements:

```
static <T> List<T> take(List<T> l, int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return newArrayList();
    } else {
        int takeTo = Math.min(Math.max(n, 0), l.size());
        return l.subList(0, takeTo);
    }
}
```

it just works like `scala.List.take`

```
    assertEquals(newArrayList(1, 2, 3), take(newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 3));
    assertEquals(newArrayList(1, 2, 3), take(newArrayList(1, 2, 3), 5));

    assertEquals(newArrayList(), take(newArrayList(1, 2, 3), -1));
    assertEquals(newArrayList(), take(newArrayList(1, 2, 3), 0));
```

now it will be fairly simple to write a `takeWhile` method based on `take`

```
static <T> List<T> takeWhile(List<T> l, Predicate<T> p) {
    return l.stream().
            filter(p.negate()).findFirst(). // find first element when p is false
            map(l::indexOf).        // find the index of that element
            map(i -> take(l, i)).   // take up to the index
            orElse(l);  // return full list if p is true for all elements
}
```

it works like this:

```
    assertEquals(newArrayList(1, 2, 3), takeWhile(newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1), i -> i < 4));
```

this implementation iterate the list partially for a few times but it won't add add `O(n^2)` operations. Hope that's acceptable.

Answer (score -3):

I have another quick solution by implementing this (which is rly unclean in fact, but you get the idea):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(StreamUtil.iterate(1, o -> o + 1).terminateOn(15)
            .map(o -> o.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
}

static interface TerminatedStream<T> {
    Stream<T> terminateOn(T e);
}

static class StreamUtil {
    static <T> TerminatedStream<T> iterate(T seed, UnaryOperator<T> op) {
        return new TerminatedStream<T>() {
            public Stream<T> terminateOn(T e) {
                Builder<T> builder = Stream.<T> builder().add(seed);
                T current = seed;
                while (!current.equals(e)) {
                    current = op.apply(current);
                    builder.add(current);
                }
                return builder.build();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You're evaluating the **whole** stream in advance! And if `current` never `.equals(e)`, you'll get an endless loop. Both even if you subsequently apply e.g. `.limit(1)`. That's far worse than *'unclean'*.

Answer (score -3):

Here is my attempt using just Java Stream library.

```
        IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
        .filter(n -> {
                if (n < 10) {
                    System.out.println(n);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            })
        .findAny();
```

Comment: [The `filter` predicate is supposed to be stateless.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#filter%28java.util.function.IntPredicate%29) `System.out.println` is a side-effect.