# Using streams to compute infinite sum

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to learn the details of using the Stream API, and one of the assignments I gave myself was to try to write a method that takes an infinite `DoubleStream` and tries to compute the sum (assuming it converges).  That is, I'd like to write a method

```
public static double infiniteSum(DoubleStream ds) { ... }
```

that I could call with something like

```
double sum = infiniteSum(IntStream.iterate(1, (i -> i + 1))
                                  .mapToDouble(n -> 1 / ((double)n * n)));
```

to get the sum (1 + 1/2<sup>2</sup> + 1/3<sup>2</sup> + ... ) = ζ(2) = π<sup>2</sup>/6.

My crude method for doing this the old way:

```
public static void yeOldeWaye() {
    double sum = 0;
    for (double n = 1; ; n++) {
        double term = 1 / (n * n);
        if (Math.abs(term) <= 1e-12 * Math.abs(sum)) {
            break;
        }
        sum += term;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

which gives me a result accurate to 5 places.

I can implement the method in a hacked way using `iterator()`:

```
public static double infiniteSum1(DoubleStream ds) {
    double sum = 0;
    PrimitiveIterator.OfDouble it = ds.iterator();
    while (true) {
        double term = it.next();
        if (Math.abs(term) <= 1e-12 * Math.abs(sum)) {
            break;
        }
        sum += term;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

but that just feels like reverting to the old way, and I was looking for a method that used streams more the way they were intended to be used, or something.

This produces the correct result:

```
private static class DoubleAccumulator {
    public double sum;
    public DoubleAccumulator() {
        sum = 0;
    }
}

public static double infiniteSum(DoubleStream ds) {
    DoubleAccumulator summer = ds.limit(800000).collect
        (DoubleAccumulator::new,
         (s, d) -> s.sum += d,
         (s1, s2) -> s1.sum += s2.sum);
    return summer.sum;
}
```

but I happened to know that the old method used almost 800000 terms, and putting a limit on the stream defeats my purpose.  The problem is that I don't see a way to cut off a stream other than by using `limit()`, which means that I have to know beforehand how many terms I'm going to have; I don't see a way to stop the stream based on some condition that's computed based on what I'm seeing in the stream.

This doesn't work:

```
public static double infiniteSum(DoubleStream ds) {
    DoubleAccumulator summer = ds.collect
        (DoubleAccumulator::new,
         (s, d) -> { if (Math.abs(d) <= 1e-12 * Math.abs(s.sum)) {
                        ds.close();  // AAACK
                     } else
                        s.sum += d;
                   },
         (s1, s2) -> s1.sum += s2.sum);
    return summer.sum;
}
```

A trace indicates that something does happen when the last term is seen, but nothing good: in one case, the computation stopped but the program still hung, and in another case, it gave me a cute little crash dump that I get to report to Oracle.

So is there a way to accomplish the sort of thing I'm looking for?

(Note: I'm assuming serial streams, for now.  But I think this is the sort of problem that could benefit from parallelism, once I figure out how to make it work.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java 8: Limit infinite stream by a predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/java-8-limit-infinite-stream-by-a-predicate)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Pretty close, although that question wanted to limit it based on a predicate that could be applied to the stream elements, and what I'm looking for is even more insidious than that.  But I'll definitely look over the earlier question.

Comment: @ajb StackOverflow(Exception) is the ideal place for infinity related questions.

Comment: Even uglier: `double[] sum = new double[1]; try { DoubleStream.iterate(1, d -> d + 1).map(d -> 1 / (d * d)).peek(term -> { sum[0] += term; if (term <= 1e-12 * sum[0]) { System.out.println(sum[0]); throw new RuntimeException(""); } }).count(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}`

Comment: @assylias I was trying to do it without exceptions... for a while I was thinking of trying `forEachRemaining` on the `iterator()` and using an exception to terminate it.  Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have such a dependency between the termination criteria and the `Collector`’s result, using mutable state is unavoidable. But as long as you don’t need parallel execution, the implementation can be straight-forward:

```
class MutableDouble {
    double sum;
}
MutableDouble sumHolder=new MutableDouble();
DoubleStream ds=IntStream.iterate(1, (i -> i + 1))
                         .mapToDouble(n -> 1 / ((double)n * n));
ds.peek(term -> sumHolder.sum+=term)
  .filter(term -> Math.abs(term)<1e-12*Math.abs(sumHolder.sum))
  .findFirst();
System.out.println(sumHolder.sum);
```

Since it will sum up before comparing it is not exactly the same as your original logic but rather like:

```
double sum = 0;
for (double n = 1; ; n++) {
    double term = 1 / (n * n);
    sum += term;
    if (Math.abs(term) <= 1e-12 * Math.abs(sum)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

If you insist on the original logic it has to be slightly more complicated:

```
class MutableDouble {
    double sum, next;
    void add(double d) {
        sum=next;
        next+=d;
    }
}
MutableDouble sumHolder=new MutableDouble();
DoubleStream ds=IntStream.iterate(1, (i -> i + 1))
                         .mapToDouble(n -> 1 / ((double)n * n));
ds.peek(sumHolder::add)
  .filter(term -> Math.abs(term)<1e-12*Math.abs(sumHolder.sum))
  .findFirst();
```

Comment: Nice--thanks.  By the way, it seems like since computers do have to compute this kind of converging sum sometimes (with algorithms much more complex than my crude one), using parallelism would definitely benefit, and I may try to look into how it would be accomplished, although I'm sure the math is way over my head.

Comment: There are ways to do it in parallel. But it does not necessarily involve the Java 8 `Stream` API.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you know that the result is ~ 1. So your comparison: `term <= 1e-12 * sum` is roughly equivalent to `term <= 1e-12`.

Now you don't need the sum at each step which simplifies the problem a bit (otherwise you can keep track of the sum in the iterator). It can then be written:

```
public static void yeStreamsWaye() {
    System.out.println(stream().sum());
}

private static DoubleStream stream() {
    return StreamSupport.doubleStream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(new Piterator(),
            Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.IMMUTABLE | Spliterator.NONNULL), false);
}

static class Piterator implements PrimitiveIterator.OfDouble {
    private double t = 1;
    @Override public boolean hasNext() { return 1 / (t * t) > 1e-12; }
    @Override public double nextDouble() { return 1 / (t * t++); }
}
```

It doesn't look like this can be easily "parallelised" and I would tend to conclude that your initial loop doesn't look so bad...

Comment: Thanks.  I don't understand the `Spliterator` stuff yet, so this will give me something to study.

Answer (score 0):

In [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate) it was mentioned that now with **Java 9** we have Stream.[takeWhile(Predicate)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) which is cool, though moving to JDK 9 for a single feature *may be* not justified, so I propose [another](https://pastebin.com/nN4Zkrg7) approach.

---

### As you wrote:

> but I happened to know that the old method used almost 800000 terms, and putting a limit on the stream defeats my purpose. The problem is that I don't see a way to cut off a stream other than by using limit(), which means that I have to know beforehand how many terms I'm going to have; I don't see a way to stop the stream based on some condition that's computed based on what I'm seeing in the stream.

this problem with finding number of most relevant terms may be solved mathematically with one simple method like following:

```
static int numOfRelevantTerms(IntToDoubleFunction termRule, double precision) {
    int[] fibonacci = {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903};
    for (int i : fibonacci) {
        double term = termRule.applyAsDouble(i);
        if (term < precision) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Alternatively, one can **avoid** having this sequence *hardcoded* and implement finding it's next term on-the-go. For fibonacci sequence see example [here](https://pastebin.com/7nauw7Ns).

Also, it could be another sequence, like exponential: 8, 16, 32, 64, ...
Then, finding next term is totally easy (though huge steps):

```
for (int n = 8; ; n *= 2) {
    if (termRule.applyAsDouble(n) < precision) {
        return n;
    }
}
```

### And finally:

```
static double findSum(IntToDoubleFunction termRule, double precision) {
    int lastInt = numOfRelevantTerms(termRule, precision);
    return IntStream.range(1, lastInt)
            .mapToDouble(termRule)
            .sum();
}
```

---

### Ps:

Although, perhaps, there's more efficient sequence for finding it, I tend to believe this one is close to optimal as fibonacci sequence is far more dynamic than quadratic and still more balanced than exponential (2^x, 1.6^x; but not 1.5^x) - see my [humble comparison](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B2pqXSbs4MaGxsXxgdTMDt5RTyo2dWCr4iV_gi7gpmA)

---

### More practical approach:

(yet it've not been mentioned too)

```
 DoubleAdder sum = new DoubleAdder();
 IntStream.closedRange(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        .mapToDouble(i -> 1.0 / i)
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .peek(sum::add)
        .anyMatch(term -> term < 0.01);
```

Hope it helps ;]