# terminate or break java 8 stream loop

Tags: java, loops, java-8, java-stream

I have a java 8 stream loop with the following content:

```
    void matchSellOrder(Market market, Order sellOrder) {
        System.out.println("selling " + market.pair() + " : " + sellOrder);

        market.buyOrders()
                .stream()
                .filter(buyOrder -> buyOrder.price >= sellOrder.price)
                .sorted(BY_ASCENDING_PRICE)
                .forEach((buyOrder) -> {
                    double tradeVolume = Math.min(buyOrder.quantity, sellOrder.quantity);
                    double price = buyOrder.price;

                    buyOrder.quantity -= tradeVolume;
                    sellOrder.quantity -= tradeVolume;

                    Trade trade = new Trade.Builder(market, price, tradeVolume, Trade.Type.SELL).build();
                    CommonUtil.convertToJSON(trade);

                    if (sellOrder.quantity == 0) {
                        System.out.println("order fulfilled");
                        // break loop there
                    }
                });
    }
```

How can I break out of loop when some condition is met?
Whats the right way to close stream anyway?

**UPDATE**

I was misusing streams tecnique assuming that it is a loop, it is not designed for that. Here's the code I've ended up using answer provided below:

```
        List<Order> applicableSortedBuyOrders = market.buyOrders()
                .stream()
                .filter(buyOrder -> buyOrder.price >= sellOrder.price)
                .sorted(BY_ASCENDING_PRICE)
                .collect(toList());

        for(Order buyOrder : applicableSortedBuyOrders){
            double tradeVolume = Math.min(buyOrder.quantity, sellOrder.quantity);
            double price = buyOrder.price;

            buyOrder.quantity -= tradeVolume;
            sellOrder.quantity -= tradeVolume;

            Trade trade = new Trade.Builder(market, price, tradeVolume, Trade.Type.SELL).build();
            CommonUtil.printAsJSON(trade);

            if (sellOrder.quantity == 0) {
                System.out.println("order fulfilled");
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This question IS a duplicate, but not so much of the question indicated, but of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308193/how-to-break-or-return-from-java8-lambda-foreach

Comment: I've not tried this but...What if you perform your work in a `peek()` consumer and follow it with an `anyMatch()` predicate on a concurrency-safe termination state object?

Comment: you may place a `sequential()` before your terminal operation to avoid concurrency problems. then just replace `forEach` with `anyMatch` and return inside the predicate `return sellOrder.quantity == 0`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`Stream.forEach` is not a loop and it's not designed for being terminated using something like `break`. If the stream is a parallel stream the lambda body could be executed on different threads at the same time (not easy to break that and it could easily produce incorrect results).

Better use a iterator with a while loop:

```
Iterator<BuyOrderType> iter = market.buyOrders() // replace BuyOrderType with correct type here
            .stream()
            .filter(buyOrder -> buyOrder.price >= sellOrder.price)
            .sorted(BY_ASCENDING_PRICE).iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    BuyOrderType buyOrder = iter.next()  // replace BuyOrderType with correct type here
    double tradeVolume = Math.min(buyOrder.quantity, sellOrder.quantity);
    double price = buyOrder.price;

    buyOrder.quantity -= tradeVolume;
    sellOrder.quantity -= tradeVolume;

    Trade trade = new Trade.Builder(market, price, tradeVolume, Trade.Type.SELL).build();
    CommonUtil.convertToJSON(trade);

    if (sellOrder.quantity == 0) {
        System.out.println("order fulfilled");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, seems i was misusing new feature.

Comment: P.S. both are of the same type "Order"

Comment: I agree with this answer, except for the first statement.

Stream.forEach is a loop.  The difference is that it's an internal loop, instead of an external loop.  Because the loop is internal you cannot call break on it.

Comment: o ye of little faith! you totally can break out of lambda loop:

    `stream.allMatch(value -> { if (...) return true; /* continue */ else return false; /* break */ });`

Comment: @yk4ever : Tell this to a parallel steam! E.g. `IntStream.range(0, 1000).boxed().parallel().allMatch(i -> {
            System.out.println(i);
            return i % 2 != 0;
        });`

Comment: I think everyone using Streams needs to read this answer!

Comment: @fabian: this also works with a parallel stream: each threaded task will stop as soon as it finds the first element that returns `false`.

Comment: @yk4ever: the only drawback, you can't use any other terminal operation on the stream anymore.

Comment: @fabian: then don't use a parallel stream

Answer (score 29):

Well, there is no method to do this in the stream api, (as far as i know).

But if you **really need it**, you can use an Exception.

**EDIT:** For the people giving -1 to this answer I'm not advertising this as an approach one should follow, it's just an option for the cases where you need it, and it does answer the question.

```
public class BreakException extends RuntimeException {...}

try {
    market.buyOrders()
            .stream()
            .filter(buyOrder -> buyOrder.price >= sellOrder.price)
            .sorted(BY_ASCENDING_PRICE)
            .forEach((buyOrder) -> {
                double tradeVolume = Math.min(buyOrder.quantity, sellOrder.quantity);
                double price = buyOrder.price;

                buyOrder.quantity -= tradeVolume;
                sellOrder.quantity -= tradeVolume;

                Trade trade = new Trade.Builder(market, price, tradeVolume, Trade.Type.SELL).build();
                CommonUtil.convertToJSON(trade);

                if (sellOrder.quantity == 0) {
                    System.out.println("order fulfilled");
                    throw new BreakException()
                }
            });
} catch (BreakException e) {
    //Stoped
}
```

Comment: This is an option too, but as far as I know throwing and handilng exception are too expensive operations in terms of performance and should be avoided (as well as finally blocks mentioned above)

Comment: Won't work with parallel streams.

Comment: Using exceptions to control program flow is not a good practice.