# How to exit from forEach if some condition matches in java 8

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream

Can somebody let me know how to exit from forEach loop if some condition matches.I am using parallel stream.

Below is my code.

```
Map<int[], String[]> indexAndColNamePairs = depMapEntry.getKey();
Set<List<String>> dataRecords = depMapEntry.getValue();

for(Map.Entry<int[], String[]> indexAndColNamePair: indexAndColNamePairs.entrySet())
{
    int refColIndex = indexAndColNamePair.getKey()[0];
    Stream<List<String>> dataRecs = dataRecords.parallelStream();
    dataRecs.forEach((row) -> {
        if(referencingValue.equals(row.get(refColIndex)))
        {
            requiredColValueAndName.put(row.get(indexAndColNamePair.getKey()[1]),
                indexAndColNamePair.getValue()[1]);
        }
});
```

`if(referencingValue.equals(row.get(refColIndex)))` then i am inserting value to map and then i need to exit.

Comment: Adding `break;` command at the end of your if block should do the trick.

Comment: I dont want to break from for loop i want to break from forEach.Also it is not possible to use break or continue in if block.

Comment: for each is still a for loop, just a different implementation of it. break should still work

Comment: i tried but it is saying break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch

Comment: I believe the only way to abort the execution of stream would be to throw an exception. Parallel threads (tasks) are likely cancelled, but that may not be instantaneous.

Comment: @CalvinP. OP is asking for java 8 forEach on stream, not "for-each" loop introduced in java 5.

Comment: Ah I was looking at the wrong bit of code. Not familiar with `.forEach` operations, but perhaps the following link will lead you in the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate

Comment: This may be closer yet. One of the answers appears to suggest using `return;` to break. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996454/terminate-or-break-java-8-stream-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your requirement, you want to execute one statement (`requiredColValueAndName.put`) for only one item in the list. Usage of `Stream.forEach` is not relevant for this use case. Instead find the item for which you want execute the statement first and then execute.

```java
Optional<List<String>> expectedRow = dataRecs.filter(row -> referencingValue.equals(row.get(refColIndex))).findFirst();
    
if(expectedRow.isPresent()) {
requiredColValueAndName.put(
    expectedRow.get().get(indexAndColNamePair.getKey()[1]),
    indexAndColNamePair.getValue()[1]);
    
}
```

Comment: `.findFirst(…)` actually is `filter(…).findFirst()`.

Answer (score 3):

You **can't**.  From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

> In almost all cases, terminal operations are eager, completing their traversal of the data source and processing of the pipeline before returning. Only the terminal operations iterator() and spliterator() are not; these are provided as an "escape hatch" to enable arbitrary client-controlled pipeline traversals in the event that the existing operations are not sufficient to the task.

What you want is either [filter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) and [findFirst()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) or [iterate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-).

Comment: ... or a plain old for-each loop! Just because we have fancy new tools, doesn't mean we shouldn't use the old ones when they do what we want!

Comment: Indeed. I am in full agreement with you; but that wasn't really the question. =)

Comment: Yup, I agree (and I did upvote your answer, fwiw). Just a friendly reminder to the OP that if they want `break` behavior, the easiest answer may be the one they've known fur years. :)

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat more functional variation of @MrinalKSamanta answer:

```
indexAndColNamePairs.forEach((indices, colNames) -> {
    int refColIndex = indices[0];
    dataRecords.parallelStream()
               .filter(row -> referencingValue.equals(row.get(refColIndex)))
               .findFirst()
               .ifPresent(row ->
                   requiredColValueAndName.put(row.get(indices[1]), colNames[1]));
});
```

Note that if you are not restricted to put exactly the first matching value (or you expect at most one matching value), you may have better performance if you replace `.findFirst()` with `.findAny()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String checkforlogin(List<String[]> ld, String iname, String ipass) {

    for (String[] u : ld) {
        Log.e("u[1]" ,u[1]);
        Log.e("u[2]" ,u[2]);

        if(u[1].toString().equals(iname) && u[2].toString().equals(ipass)){
            System.out.println("Bingo!!!" + u[0] + " " + u[1] + " " + u[2]);
            //go the the MainActivity
            retur_val = u[0];
        }else{
            if(retur_val.equals("-1"))
            {
                retur_val = "-1";
            }else {
                Log.e("already" , "got the value");
            }
```

//                return retur_val;

```
        }
    }
    return retur_val;
}
```

//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
retur_val is a calss variable which is "-1"