# What is the forEach method with lambda expression in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Where does this `forEach` method come from in the following code? It was a suggested fix, and I have not written a forEach method and as far as I can find, List does not implement one either.

```
List<String> players = Arrays.asList(temp);
//using lambda expression and functional operations
players.forEach(person) -> System.out.print(person + "; "));
```

How does it know to iterate over the entire list and perform the given lambda expression?

Comment: it was a method from [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to break or return from Java8 Lambda forEach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308193/how-to-break-or-return-from-java8-lambda-foreach)

Comment: I disagree on the duplicate. That thread vaguely discusses when or not to use the `forEach` method, they do not discuss where it comes or what it has to do with lambdas.

Comment: FYI, there should not be a right parenthesis after the first `person`.  I.e. `players.forEach(person -> System.out.print(person + "; "));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List` implements [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) which contains [`forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-).

When in doubt, [check the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (see "Methods inherited from interface java.lang.Iterable" section).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I thought I thoroughly checked through to see if the method was defined but I missed it.

Comment: @bmcentee148 Inherited members aren't always obvious in javadocs since they aren't in the main list. It often also helps to do a text search on the page in case it is buried somewhere.