# Java Stream vs Scala Stream

Tags: java, scala, java-stream

Consider the following Scala code:

```
var myStream = Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

var cnt = 0;

def duplicate(in: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] = {
  in.flatMap(elem => {
    cnt += 1
    Stream(elem, elem)
  })
}

myStream = duplicate(myStream)
myStream = duplicate(myStream)
myStream = duplicate(myStream)
myStream = duplicate(myStream)

"First elem: " + myStream.head
"cnt: " + cnt
"Size: " + myStream.size
"cnt: " + cnt
```

Last 4 lines prints:

```
First elem: 1
cnt: 4
Size: 160
cnt: 150
```

Which is exactly as expected. 
To calculate first element it is required to run *flatMap* 4 times therefore cnt is equal to 4 at that step.

Now consider Java example:

```
static int cnt = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntStream range = IntStream.range(1, 11);
    range = duplicate(range);
    range = duplicate(range);
    range = duplicate(range);
    range = duplicate(range);
    System.out.println(
            range.findAny()//range.findFirst()
    );
    System.out.println(cnt);
    //System.out.println(
    //      range.count()
    //);
    //System.out.println(cnt);
}
private static IntStream duplicate(IntStream elem) {
    return elem.flatMap(e -> {
        ++cnt;
        return IntStream.of(e, e);
    });
}
```

Java sample needs to be run twice as find is terminal operation. 
So after two runs:

```
first element is: OptionalInt[1]
cnt: 15
Size: 160
cnt: 150
```

It looks likes steam laziness is somehow broken in Java. 
I have no idea why Java needs 15 (*cnt: 15*) *flatMap* operations to calculate results.

For small examples this is not an issue, but for much more complicated flow this can cause performance problems when one only cares about first stream element.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/29229373/1743880

Comment: findFirst() and findAny() returns the same for this sample

Comment: *@Tunaki Related stackoverflow.com/q/29229373/1743880*
<br/> Yep, my questions is duplicated of that one. Thanks.

Comment: For everyone who loose  hope, moving to RxJava should resolve the issue.