# java stream filter based on different fields

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream of object Person. I want to find people with height>6 and if there exists no one that matches that criteria, then I wanna find people with weight>100. I'm achieving it the following way but wondering if I can get it done in a better way.

```
Optional<Person> personWithHeightGreaterThan6 = persons.stream()
        .filter(person -> person.getHeight()>6)
        .findFirst();
if (personWithHeightGreaterThan6.isPresent()) {
        result = personWithHeightGreaterThan6.get();
} else {
Optional<Person> personWithWeightGreaterThan100 = persons.stream()
        .filter(person -> person.getWeight()>100)
        .findFirst();
    if (personWithWeightGreaterThan100.isPresent()) {
            result = personWithWeightGreaterThan100.get();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your criteria for "better"?

Comment: basically I don't like the idea of having multiple if elses. I was hoping if it could be achieved with a single stream.

Comment: Is it performance or cleanliness you're after?

Comment: cleanliness would be preferred for my usecase.

Comment: That's obviously going to be subjective, but see my answer for a possible approach. I may have another idea I'll post once I get to a computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that tries to find an element by matching against an array of filters ordered by priority. If it doesn't find a match against any filter it will return null.

```
@SafeVarargs
static <T> T findFirst(List<T> elements, Predicate<? super T>... filters) {
    return Arrays.stream(filters)
            .map(f -> elements.stream().filter(f).findFirst())
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
Person result = findFirst(persons,
        person -> person.getHeight() > 6,
        person -> person.getWeight() > 100);
```

Might be a little overkill, but it's not really clear what kind of improvement you're looking for.

Comment: “Might be a little overkill, but” what the OP has asked for. Good job; I just added the alternatives to `.filter(Optional::isPresent) .map(Optional::get)`…

Answer (score 3):

[shmosel’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46657137/2711488) can be simplified as

```
@SafeVarargs
static <T> T findFirst(List<T> elements, Predicate<? super T>... filters) {
    return Arrays.stream(filters)
            .flatMap(f -> elements.stream().filter(f))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Unfortunately, with the current Stream implementation, using `flatMap` has a small performance disadvantage over the other solution, as discussed in “[Why filter() after flatMap() is “not completely” lazy in Java streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29229373/2711488)”, but for most practical use cases, it might be sufficient.

Java 9 is offering an in-between solution with full laziness and almost as simple as the one above:

```
@SafeVarargs
static <T> T findFirst(List<T> elements, Predicate<? super T>... filters) {
    return Arrays.stream(filters)
            .flatMap(f -> elements.stream().filter(f).findFirst().stream())
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: Didn't think of using `flatMap()`. Very nice.