# takeWhile() working differently with flatmap

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, java-9

I am creating snippets with takeWhile to explore its possibilities. When used in conjunction with flatMap, the behaviour is not in line with the expectation. Please find the code snippet below.

```
String[][] strArray = {{"Sample1", "Sample2"}, {"Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5"}};

Arrays.stream(strArray)
        .flatMap(indStream -> Arrays.stream(indStream))
        .takeWhile(ele -> !ele.equalsIgnoreCase("Sample4"))
        .forEach(ele -> System.out.println(ele));
```

Actual Output:

```
Sample1
Sample2
Sample3
Sample5
```

ExpectedOutput:

```
Sample1
Sample2
Sample3
```

Reason for the expectation is that takeWhile should be executing till the time the condition inside turns true. I have also added printout statements inside flatmap for debugging. The streams are returned just twice which is inline with the expectation.

However, this works just fine without flatmap in the chain.

```
String[] strArraySingle = {"Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5"};
Arrays.stream(strArraySingle)
        .takeWhile(ele -> !ele.equalsIgnoreCase("Sample4"))
        .forEach(ele -> System.out.println(ele));
```

Actual Output:

```
Sample3
```

Here the actual output matches with the expected output.

Disclaimer: These snippets are just for code practise and does not serve any valid usecases.

**Update:** 
Bug [JDK-8193856](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193856): fix will be available as part of JDK 10.
The change will be to correct `whileOps`
Sink::accept

```
@Override 
public void accept(T t) {
    if (take = predicate.test(t)) {
        downstream.accept(t);
    }
}
```

Changed Implementation:

```
@Override
public void accept(T t) {
    if (take && (take = predicate.test(t))) {
        downstream.accept(t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is a bug in JDK 9 - from [issue #8193856](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193856):

> `takeWhile` is incorrectly assuming that an upstream operation supports and honors cancellation, which unfortunately is not the case for `flatMap`.

## Explanation

If the stream is ordered, `takeWhile` should show the expected behavior. This is not entirely the case in your code because you use `forEach`, which waives order. If you care about it, which you do in this example, you should use `forEachOrdered` instead. Funny thing: That doesn't change anything.

So maybe the stream isn't ordered in the first place? (In that case [the behavior is ok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47889224/2525313).) If you create a temporary variable for the stream created from `strArray` and check whether it is ordered by executing the expression `((StatefulOp) stream).isOrdered();` at the breakpoint, you will find that it is indeed ordered:

```
String[][] strArray = {{"Sample1", "Sample2"}, {"Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5"}};

Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(strArray)
        .flatMap(indStream -> Arrays.stream(indStream))
        .takeWhile(ele -> !ele.equalsIgnoreCase("Sample4"));

// breakpoint here
System.out.println(stream);
```

That means that this is very likely an implementation error.

## Into The Code

As others have suspected, I now also think that this *might* be connected to `flatMap` being eager. More precisely, both problems might have the same root cause.

Looking into the source of `WhileOps`, we can see these methods:

```
@Override
public void accept(T t) {
    if (take = predicate.test(t)) {
        downstream.accept(t);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean cancellationRequested() {
    return !take || downstream.cancellationRequested();
}
```

This code is used by `takeWhile` to check for a given stream element `t` whether the `predicate` is fulfilled:

- If so, it passes the element on to the `downstream` operation, in this case `System.out::println`.
- If not, it sets `take` to false, so when it is asked next time whether the pipeline should be canceled (i.e. it is done), it returns `true`.

This covers the `takeWhile` operation. The other thing you need to know is that `forEachOrdered` leads to the terminal operation executing the method `ReferencePipeline::forEachWithCancel`:

```
@Override
final boolean forEachWithCancel(Spliterator<P_OUT> spliterator, Sink<P_OUT> sink) {
    boolean cancelled;
    do { } while (
            !(cancelled = sink.cancellationRequested())
            && spliterator.tryAdvance(sink));
    return cancelled;
}
```

All this does is:

1. check whether pipeline was canceled
2. if not, advance the sink by one element
3. stop if this was the last element

Looks promising, right?

### Without `flatMap`

In the "good case" (without `flatMap`; your second example) `forEachWithCancel` directly operates on the `WhileOp` as `sink` and you can see how this plays out:

- `ReferencePipeline::forEachWithCancel` does its loop:

  - `WhileOps::accept` is given each stream element
  - `WhileOps::cancellationRequested` is queried after each element
- at some point `"Sample4"` fails the predicate and the stream is canceled

Yay!

### With `flatMap`

In the "bad case" (with `flatMap`; your first example), `forEachWithCancel` operates on the `flatMap` operation, though, , which simply calls `forEachRemaining` on the `ArraySpliterator` for `{"Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5"}`, which does this:

```
if ((a = array).length >= (hi = fence) &&
    (i = index) >= 0 && i < (index = hi)) {
    do { action.accept((T)a[i]); } while (++i < hi);
}
```

Ignoring all that `hi` and `fence` stuff, which is only used if the array processing is split for a parallel stream, this is a simple `for` loop, which passes each element to the `takeWhile` operation, **but never checks whether it is cancelled**. It will hence eagerly ply through all elements in that "substream" before stopping, likely even [through the rest of the stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888814/takewhile-working-differently-with-flatmap/47890166?noredirect=1#comment82752871_47890166).

Comment: @Eugene: well, I bet it’s connected to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29229373/2711488). It happened to work for terminal short-circuiting operations, because they ignore excess elements, but now we have intermediate short circuiting operations… So it’s actually good news, as it implies that now there is some more pressure to fix that bug (lousy performance or breaking when the sub-streams are infinite apparently wasn’t enough)…

Comment: It does not iterate through the entire stream. If the last element of a sub-stream matches the predicate, the outer stream’s cancellation support will work, e.g. use `String[][] strArray = { {"Sample1", "Sample2"}, {"Sample3", "Sample4"}, {"Sample5", "Sample6"}, };` as input and it appears to work. If only an in-between element matches, `flatMap`’s ignorance towards cancellation causes the flag to be overwritten with the subsequent element’s evaluation.

Comment: @Holger I meant that "substream" only (which wasn't clear from my phrasing) and didn't even think about following "substream". Changed the wording and linked to your comment from clarification.

Comment: Seems, they've heard you: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193856

Answer (score 20):

This *is* a bug no matter how I look at it - and thank you Holger for your comments. I did not want to put this answer in here (seriously!), but none of the answer clearly states that this is a bug.

People are saying that this has to with ordered/un-ordered, and this is not true as this will report `true` 3 times:

```
Stream<String[]> s1 = Arrays.stream(strArray);
System.out.println(s1.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.ORDERED));

Stream<String> s2 = Arrays.stream(strArray)
            .flatMap(indStream -> Arrays.stream(indStream));
System.out.println(s2.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.ORDERED));

Stream<String> s3 = Arrays.stream(strArray)
            .flatMap(indStream -> Arrays.stream(indStream))
            .takeWhile(ele -> !ele.equalsIgnoreCase("Sample4"));
System.out.println(s3.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.ORDERED));
```

It's very interesting also that if you change it to:

```
String[][] strArray = { 
         { "Sample1", "Sample2" }, 
         { "Sample3", "Sample5", "Sample4" }, // Sample4 is the last one here
         { "Sample7", "Sample8" } 
};
```

then `Sample7` and `Sample8` will not be part of the output, otherwise they will. It seems that `flatmap` *ignores* a cancel flag that would be introduced by `dropWhile`.

Answer (score 11):

If you look at [the documentation for `takeWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-):

> if this stream is ordered, [returns] a stream consisting of the
>   longest prefix of elements taken from this stream that match the given
>   predicate.
>
> if this stream is unordered, [returns] a stream consisting of a subset
>   of elements taken from this stream that match the given predicate.

Your stream is coincidentally ordered, but `takeWhile` *doesn't know* that it is. As such, it is returning 2nd condition - the subset. Your `takeWhile` is just acting like a [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-).

If you add a call to [`sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted--) before `takeWhile`, you'll see the result you expect:

```
Arrays.stream(strArray)
      .flatMap(indStream -> Arrays.stream(indStream))
      .sorted()
      .takeWhile(ele -> !ele.equalsIgnoreCase("Sample4"))
      .forEach(ele -> System.out.println(ele));
```

Comment: Why is it not ordered, or why doesn't it know that it is? the "concatenation" of ordered streams should be ordered, shouldn't it?

Comment: @JBNizet `takeWhile` uses a flag which a property of the stream to determine whether or not it's ordered. The fact that the stream is in fact ordered when it says it isn't is presumably an implementation detail not to be relied upon.

Comment: @JBNizet but then if you take each separate step `Stream<String[]> s1 = Arrays.stream(strArray); System.out.println(s1.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Split‌​erator.ORDERED))` and so on for each step - they will all produce a `ORDERED` stream, this looks like a bug that is not yet reported

Comment: @Michael as I see it (according to the previous comment) - your conclusion is wrong to me

Comment: “*but takeWhile doesn't know that it is*”… well *why* doesn’t it know it when the stream and its sub-stream *are* ordered and why is `.sorted().unordered() .takeWhile(…)` still doing the right thing then? I’d say, it’s because `sorted` is a stateful operation that buffers the entire input, followed by a truly lazy iteration.

Comment: "Your stream is coincidentally ordered, but takeWhile doesn't know that it is. As such, it is returning 2nd condition - the subset. Your takeWhile is just acting like a filter.": But this sounds really wrong. If the stream is not ordered, it will return its elements in some unpredictable order. Now, `takeWhile` should act on the elements it actually receives in the order it receives them, and stop as soon as an element does not satisfy its predicate. If one wants to filter on an unordered stream, they should use `filter`.

Answer (score 9):

The reason for that is the [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) operation also being an [intermediate operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) with which (one of) the ***stateful short-circuiting intermediate operation*** [`takeWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) is used.

The behavior of `flatMap` as pointed by Holger in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229373/why-filter-after-flatmap-is-not-completely-lazy-in-java-streams/29230939#29230939) is certainly a reference one shouldn't miss out to understand the unexpected output for such short-circuiting operations.

Your expected result can be achieved by splitting these two intermediate operations by introducing a terminal operation to deterministically use an ordered stream further and performing them for a sample as :

```
List<String> sampleList = Arrays.stream(strArray).flatMap(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
sampleList.stream().takeWhile(ele -> !ele.equalsIgnoreCase("Sample4"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Also, there seems to be a related [Bug#JDK-8075939](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075939) to trace this behavior already registered.

***Edit***: This can be tracked further at [JDK-8193856](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193856) accepted as a bug.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation. To me this behavior seems like a bug. And your suggested alternative requires two Stream pipelines, which might be less desirable.

Comment: @Eran Indeed the behavior seems like a bug. The alternative suggested is just to introduce a terminal operation to complete(exhaust) `flatMap` operation and then process the stream for executing `takeWhile`.