# Why does collecting after flatMap change Stream processing order?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

When I run the following code:

```
    Stream.of("a", "b", "c")
        .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s, s+s))
        .map(s -> {System.out.printf("complex operation on %s\n", s); return s;})
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(s -> System.out.printf("outcome %s\n", s));
```

...the `map` operation runs for the first two elements in the stream, instead of just the first one:

```
complex operation on a
complex operation on aa
outcome a
```

However, if I explicitly `collect` after the `flatMap`:

```
    Stream.of("a", "b", "c")
        .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s, s + s))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .stream()
        .map(s -> {System.out.printf("complex operation on %s\n", s); return s;})
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(s -> System.out.printf("outcome %s\n", s));
```

...then the `map` operation runs on only the first element, as I'd expect.

**Why is there a difference, and how can I can I get the `map` to only process the first item without collecting the whole incoming stream?**

Please note that this is not my actual code. In practice I need to `filter` after the `map` and before the `findFirst`, so I can't do something like call `findFirst` before `map`.

I also tried:

- `.sequential()` after the `flatMap` (no effect)
- `.sorted()` after the `flatMap` (works, but reads the whole stream, and in my real application it doesn't actually make sense to sort)

Comment: First time  i have seen question ,flag , answer by same person ;).

Comment: Collections are not lazy. By asking to create a collection, you are explicitly telling it to be fully evaluated before continuing. A stream is already sequential() by default. `sorted()` has to collect all element to find the smallest one. There is no way around this without knowledge of what the minimum values are.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer to the root cause is also here: [Why filter() after flatMap() is "not completely" lazy in Java streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229373/why-filter-after-flatmap-is-not-completely-lazy-in-java-streams)

Apparently it's a known bug that will be fixed in Java 10. See [JDK-8075939](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8075939).