# Using Java streams, how to filter a collection such that the result contains all elements up until a match is found?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

If I have a `List` containing objects like

```
new MyObj("some"),
new MyObj("foo"),
new MyObj("bar"),
new MyObj("xyz");
```

and want to filter it with Java 8 streams **after match** some condition, say

```
myObj.prop = "foo";
```

how would that be accomplished?

The result of the above example should be

```
new MyObj("some"),
new MyObj("foo")
```

That would be the "traditional" way:

```
List<MyObj> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (MyObj myObj : myObjList) {
  if (!myObj.prop.equals("foo")) {
    results.add(myObj);
  } else {
    results.add(myObj);
    break;
  }
}
```

It is not exaclty a duplicate of [Limit a stream by a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate) because that does not **include** the matched element. However, I should be able to adapt the takeWhile operation.

Comment: @AndyTurner he wants to return all elements up until that condition is met

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308193/break-or-return-from-java-8-stream-foreach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately such scenario is not directly supported by Stream API. Even `takeWhile`, which is newly appeared method in Java 9 would not solve this. Some free third-party Stream API extensions have a method you need. For example, [limitWhileClosed](http://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html#limitWhileClosed-java.util.function.Predicate-) in [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL/) or [takeWhileInclusive](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/AbstractStreamEx.html#takeWhileInclusive-java.util.function.Predicate-) in [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) (the library I wrote). Here's an example, how to do it via StreamEx:

```
List<MyObj> results = StreamEx.of(myObjList)
    .takeWhileInclusive(myObj -> !myObj.prop.equals("foo")).toList();
```

jOOλ version would look pretty similar.

Without using third-party libraries you can solve this in two passes:

```
int idx = IntStream.range(0, myObjList.size())
         .filter(i -> myObjList.get(i).prop.equals("foo"))
         .findFirst().orElse(myObjList.size());

List<MyObj> results = myObjList.stream().limit(idx+1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: …or `results = idx==myObjList.size()? myObjList: myObjList.subList(0, idx+1);`, depending on the use case.