# How to find any element in a HashMap where a given condition about that element is true

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

- Given an object, `MyObj` which for our purposes holds `String message` among other fields.
- Given a HashMap, `Map <MultiKey<String>,MyObj> map`.

I want to loop through the HashMap finding any element where the MyObj's message is `searchValue`. I'm essentially trying to use `stream().anyMatch()` on a Map, I simply want to know if `searchValue` exists even once anywhere - i.e. short circuiting is preferable.

Foreach loop:

```
map.forEach((k,v) -> {
    if (v.message.equalsIgnoreCase(searchValue)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The issue with this is that it doesn't terminate early, neither `break` or `return` can be used in this lambda to terminate the loop early.

I see the stream anyMatch() function:

```
 map.entrySet().stream().anymatch(....
```

but I can't figure out the proper syntax - if that will work in this case at all (can it still be used if I'm not comparing the map's elements, rather I'm comparing each element's fields).

Comment: `map.values().stream().map(v -> v.message).anyMatch(searchValue::equalsIgnoreCase)`

Comment: FWIW, the notion of "first" doesn't really mean much for a standard `HashMap`, as its entries aren't sequenced/ordered.

Comment: @LouisWasserman that seemed to me worth to be written as answer (one-liner as it is): `final String searchValue = ...; boolean has = map.values().stream().map(MyObj::message).anyMatch(searchValue::equalsIgnoreCase);`

Comment: @JoopEggen `.map(MyObj::message)` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: forEach calls a method defined by your lambda for each element. If you return from this method handling one element, it doesn't terminate the entire foreach block, but only the "current" block of the one element. You can't terminate foreach any way, only by killing the entire thread (or system exit). Or maybe anybody knows any way?

Comment: Your question is too vague.  Are you (A) Trying to find and return the "first" element that matches (understanding that "first" has no meaning); or (B) Determine only IF such an element exists, terminating the search after one such element is found?  I suspect it is (B).

Comment: @JimGarrison B - "I just want to know if  searchValue exists even once." -- clarified more as well.

Comment: @fairtrax Based on [previous StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32566745/4867303) questions you terminate in middle by throwing an exception, which is very bad practice.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The first was only used in the title, not in the body.  I have edited it.  I meant to use first to mean in the sense of short circuiting, not literally the first one.

Comment: @CeePlusPlus: indeed, thanks, how could I forget an exception :)

Comment: @CeePlusPlus Louis Wasserman had an almost working version IMHO, I varied a bit, but `v -> v.message` should have worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working answers from previous posters (is there a way to tell which is more efficient?)

```
 //Note: anyMatch can be switched with noneMatch if need be
```

@JimGarrison: (seems the shortest/readable):

```
if (map.values().stream().anyMatch(v -> v.message.equalsIgnoreCase(searchValue))
    {...}
```

@Louis Wasserman:

```
if (map.values().stream().map(v -> v.message).anyMatch(searchValue::equalsIgnoreCase)) 
   {...}
```

@P3trur0:

```
if (null != map.values().stream().filter(v -> v.message.equalsIgnoreCase(searchValue)).findAny().orElse(null))
    {...}
```

Comment: I'd just do `map.values().stream().anyMatch(v -> v.message.equalsIgnoreCase(searchValue));`  This will short-circuit the stream when the first match is encountered.

Comment: @JimGarrison while yours certainly seems the simplest and more readable, how can I tell which ones short-circuit and which don't?

Comment: By understanding how streams work (intermediate vs terminal operations) and carefully reading the Javadoc.

Comment: `stream.filter(condition).find{Any|First}().orElse(null) != null` can never be better than `stream.anyMatch(condition)`

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve that is by using `findFirst` method.

In your case, for example, you can write something like this:

```
 map.values().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.message.equalsIgnoreCase(searchValue))
            .findFirst()
            .get();
```

Comment: are you sure it will work? Hashmap is not sorted and order of returning elements is  random.

Comment: @Vadim CeePlusPlus states that "I want to loop through the HashMap finding a single element where the MyObj's message is", it seems to me he is not mentioning any order.

Comment: He can just use .sorted() before or after .filter()

Comment: @P3trur0 First, I'm assuming I should be use map.values(), correct?  Secondly, how do I actually check the return value?  Is there a way to simply get a boolean or am I supposed to attempt to catch `NoSuchElementException`?  Also findFirst() vs findAny()?

Comment: maybe - but that "first" element will be always different key/object pair. If it is OK to CeePlusPlus then fine...

Comment: @CeePlusPlus you can use orElse() to return specific value if there is no queried value in the stream.

Comment: @Vadim Order is irrelevant - it's meant to be used to see if data was available for a particular message.

Comment: @CeePlusPlus findFirst() returns an Optional<T>, than as pointed out by Fair Play, you can use any Optional method to deal with possible not returning values (e.g.: .orElse(...)). In my example I've used the get() method.

Comment: Final way I'm using this one works if you want to update answer:

 `if (null != map.values().stream().filter(e -> e.message.equalsIgnoreCase(searchValue)).findAny().orElse(null);`