# Equivalent of Scala dropWhile

Tags: java, scala, java-8, java-stream

I'm struggling to find a way to skip some elements at the beginning of a stream depending on a predicate.

Something like this:

```
dropWhile( n -> n < 3, Stream.of( 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ) )
.forEach( System.out::println );
```

```
3   
0
1
2
3
4
```

That is the equivalent of Scala `dropWhile`.

Comment: Related: [Limit a stream by a predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20746429)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This kind of operation is not an intended use case for `Stream`s as it incorporates a dependency between the elements. Therefore the solution might not look elegant as you have to introduce a state-full variable for your predicate:

```
class MutableBoolean { boolean b; }
MutableBoolean inTail = new MutableBoolean();

IntStream.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
         .filter(i -> inTail.b || i >= 3 && (inTail.b = true))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note that the condition had to be reversed compared to your example.

Of course, you can hide the nasty details in a method:

```
public static void main(String... arg) {
    dropWhile(n -> n < 3, Stream.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
}
static <T> Stream<T> dropWhile(Predicate<T> p, Stream<T> s) {
    class MutableBoolean { boolean b; }
    MutableBoolean inTail = new MutableBoolean();
    return s.filter(i -> inTail.b || !p.test(i) && (inTail.b = true));
}
```

---

A more complex, but cleaner and potentially more efficient way is to go down to the metal, i.e the `Spliterator` interface:

```
static <T> Stream<T> dropWhile(Predicate<T> p, Stream<T> s) {
    Spliterator<T> sp = s.spliterator();
    return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(
            sp.estimateSize(), sp.characteristics() & ~Spliterator.SIZED) {
        boolean dropped;
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            if(dropped) return sp.tryAdvance(action);
            do {} while(!dropped && sp.tryAdvance(t -> {
                if(!p.test(t)) {
                    dropped=true;
                    action.accept(t);
                }
            }));
            return dropped;
        }
        public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super T> action) {
            while(!dropped) if(!tryAdvance(action)) return;
            sp.forEachRemaining(action);
        }
    }, s.isParallel());
}
```

this method can be used the same way as the first `dropWhile` method, but it will work even with parallel streams, though not as efficient as you might wish.

Comment: A little late with this, but did you consider using an `AtomicBoolean` rather than the `MutableBoolean` class?

Comment: @Henrik: an `AtomicBoolean` would pretend a thread safety that isn’t there for this operation, as the order of the predicate evaluation is undefined. Further, you are then potentially wasting performance using a thread safe construct for an operation that doesn’t work in parallel anyway. The locally used `MutableBoolean`, on the other hand, clearly shows what you can expect.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks.

Comment: @Holger I find `boolean[] flag = { false };` makes a reasonable non thread safe mutable boolean.

Comment: @PeterLawrey creating a dedicated class or using an array, is mostly a matter of coding style.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, the only way to do that with Java 8 is with the solution provided by [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger).

However, the operation [`dropWhile(predicate)`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) has been [added to Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32304570/1743880) so starting from JDK 9, you can simply have:

```
Stream.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4).dropWhile(n -> n < 3).forEach(System.out::println);
```