# What is the most optimized way to get a set of rows which is present in the middle of the list in java 8?

Tags: optimization, java-8, java-stream

I've a list of items. I want to process a set of items which are in the middle of the list.
Ex: Assume a list of employees who have id, first name, last name and middle name as attributes.
I want to consider all rows between lastName "xxx" and "yyy" and process them further.
How can this be optimized in Java8? Optimization is my first concern. 
Tried using Java8 streams and parallel streams. But termination(break) is not allowed in foreach loop in Java8 streams. Also we cannot use the outside("start" variable below) variables inside foreach.
Below is the code which I need to optimize:

```
boolean start = false;
for(Employee employee: employees) {
    if(employee.getLastname().equals("yyy")) {
        break;
    } 
    if(start) {
    // My code to process
    }
    if(employee.getLastname().equals("xxx")) {
        start = true;
    }
}
```

What is the best way to handle the above problem in Java8?

Answer (score 1):

That is possible in java-9 via (I've simplified your example):

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
            .dropWhile(x -> x != 2)
            .takeWhile(x -> x != 6)
            .skip(1)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This will get the values in the range `2 - 6`, that is it will print `3,4,5`.

Or for your example:

```
employees.stream()
         .dropWhile(e -> e.getLastname().equals("xxx"))
         .takeWhile(e -> e.getLastname().equals("yyy"))
         .skip(1)
         .forEach(....)
```

There are back-ports for `dropWhile` and `takeWhile`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25570609/1059372) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate)

**EDIT**

Or you can get the indexes of those delimiters first and than do a `subList` (but this assumes that `xxx` and `yyy` are unique in the list of employees):

```
int[] indexes = IntStream.range(0, employees.size())
            .filter(x -> list.get(x).getLastname().equals("xxx") || list.get(x).getLastname().equals("yyy"))
            .toArray();

employees.subList(indexes[0] + 1, indexes[1])
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that optimization of the above code is not possible in Java8? Whatever the primitive code I've written is the only solution here because I cannot go with Java9 at all.

Comment: @User1230321 see edit, there are back-ports of those in java-8

Comment: Your second variant only works, if the `"yyy"` last name is unique.

Comment: @Holger agreed... or `xxx` is unique too. I'll add that to the answer

Comment: Well, if `xxx` is not unique, your code still does the same as the original code (only skip the first occurrence), though, it should be `.dropWhile(e -> !e.getLastname().equals("xxx"))`. But it’s behavioral different for multiple `yyy`s.

Comment: Oh, my last comment assumed you used `indexes[indexes.length -2]` rather than `indexes[1]`. I should read with more care.

Comment: So, to reproduce the OP’s code behavior, you could use `int size = employees.size(), start = IntStream.range(0, size) .filter(x -> employees.get(x).getLastname().equals("xxx")) .findFirst().orElse(size - 1) + 1,  end = IntStream.range(start, size) .filter(x -> employees.get(x).getLastname().equals("yyy")) .findFirst().orElse(size);`, followed by `employees.subList(start, end).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: For this, you've to walk through the array twice which is not optimized solution I assume. What do you say?

Comment: @User1230321 this is really doubtful; I mean you have some branching inside your code via `if/else` too... so this has to be measured first, before it's judged. Usually traversing an list/array is not as slow as people tend to think

Comment: @User1230321 did my answer help you here btw?

Comment: @Eugene: It's almost similar. Around 10ms of difference is there. That's all.