# Java 8 Stream termination

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a way I can terminate a Stream (apart from `.limit(long)`).

What I'm really looking for is a kind of `.until(Predicate<T>)`. Method `filter` is obviously not usable here.

Example:

```
Stream.iterate(service.first(), service::next)
  .until(item -> item.isTerminator())
```

This example might not make sense, but shows the concept I'm looking for.

Is it even possible to do something like that?

Comment: [Seems not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/java-8-limit-infinite-stream-by-a-predicate), however interesting.

Comment: U can use this ( and make it a little more clean) : 

static interface TerminatedStream<T> {Stream<T> terminateOn(T e);}

 static class StreamUtil {static <T> TerminatedStream<T> iterate(T seed, UnaryOperator<T> op) {
   return new TerminatedStream<T>() {
    public Stream<T> terminateOn(T e) {
     Builder<T> builder = Stream.<T> builder().add(seed);
     T current = seed;
     while (!current.equals(e)) {
      current = op.apply(current);
      builder.add(current);
     }
     return builder.build();
    }
   };
  }
 }

Comment: With some changes, this works with predicate. However it stores up the values in "terminateOn" which ruins the whole concept of using Streams :)

Comment: in how far? you dont mix up streams with io.streams do you? a stream is, as far as i know, a pipe-like representation of a collection, so it has a fixed size anyway and does not react to additional input in any way. An "infinite" stream is also not a mutable object supplied by constant input but one object that is finished after infinite recursion (never, if you dont set a limit). Please correct or tell me what meant with "ruins", I dont have a lot of knowledge here to be honest.

Comment: No Streams are not simply a representation of an old style collection. See Stream.iterate(), which is an infinite stream of objects. You can convert into a collection using a collector at the end, that's true, but in between it will never be a collection. Your code is nice, but builds up a static, in-memory collection of elements as a stream, does not delegate fetching to the upstream (as limit(long) method does).