# How to find a set of any start location to between any last required location using lambdas

Tags: java, lambda

how to find a set of any start location to between any last  required location using lambdas

I am not familiar of this new java feature of lambda, I have an `arraylist` in generic class Location and I want to get a set of objects from a starting location (`Object.element`) to a specific location

```
   void find(){

      int Sindex;
      int Eindex;

      String stationName=(String)  to.getSelectedItem();// combo box
      String stationNameEnd=(String)  from.getSelectedItem();// get from combo box
      Controller manager=new Controller();

      manager.station.stream().forEach((entrySet) -> {
         if (entrySet.getStopName().equals(stationName)) {
             Sindex= manager.station.indexOf(entrySet);
             if(!entrySet.getStopName().equalsIgnoreCase(stationNameEnd)){
               dist=dist +    entrySet.getDistanceforlaststation();

               TolalPrice=TolalPrice+ entrySet.getPrice();
               Name=stationName;
               Name+=", "+ entrySet.getStopName();
               time= time+entrySet.getTime();
               point=point+entrySet.getPoints();
            }
        }
   });
```

**Problem**: I am not familiar of this new java feature of lambda

**Case 1.1:** I have an `arraylist` in generic class Location

**Case 1.2:** and I want to get a set of object

**case 2:** from find starting `Object.element` and

**case 2.1:** also stop to at specific location

What I have to do through lambda

Comment: What would your code look like without lambdas?

Comment: I *think* what you're looking for are implementations of `skipUntil()` and `takeWhile()` on Java 8 Streams.  Unfortunately, these are not supported natively in Java but there is 3rd party support.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/java-8-limit-infinite-stream-by-a-predicate

Comment: thanks CocoNess for improve my question