# Java 8 parallel streams: best way implement result limit?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, fork-join

What is the best way to implement a result limit when collecting data via Java 8 parallel streams?

```
objects.parallelStream().forEach((object) -> {
  ... complex logic here ...
  if (allGood) {
    someCollection.add(someData);
    someMap.putAll(someEntries);
  }
}
```

What is the best way to halt all further processing once the size of 'someCollection' has reached a result limit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/java-8-limit-infinite-stream-by-a-predicate

Comment: Not sure, but how about `parallelStream() .filter(functionToDetermineAllGood) .limit(number).forEach(...)`?

Comment: There is no good way. Limits and parallel execution don’t play well together. It all depends on the question, which compromise you are willing to accept.