# Lambda expressions in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda

I want to generate a list of numbers using lambda expressions and not a for-loop.

So let's say I want to generate a list of all triangular numbers under 100. Triangular numbers are numbers which follow the formula: (n*n+n)/2

What is the best way of doing this?
Currently I have this:

```
    Stream.iterate(1, n -> n + 1).limit(100)
            .map(n -> (n * n + n) / 2)
            .filter(a -> a < 100)
            .map(a -> a + "")
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "Numbers: ", "."));
```

But this seems unnecessarily overkill with the amount of calculations. I iterate n over 1 to 100 (because lets assume I do not know what the max value for n is), then I map the triangle number function of that list and then I check which numbers are under 100. Is there a more efficient way in doing this?
Also: can I generate the triangle numbers using only the iterate function of Stream instead of using iterate, limit and then map?

EDIT:
So the main point here is: **how can calculation of traingle numbers stop as soon as one of the triangle numbers exceeds 100?**
Usually I would write it like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> triangles = new ArrayList<>(); 
for (int n=1;true;n++) {
    int num = (n*n+n)/2;

    if (num>100) break;

    triangles.add(num);
}
```

which stops as soon as a triangle number exceeds 100, which is very efficient; how can I retain this efficiency in lambda expression?

Comment: `Stream.iterate(1, n->n+1).limit(100)` can be rewritten as `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)` which is probably more readable.

Comment: why are you using both a limit and a filter? I believe the second filter will limit the output based on the calculation, so you'll only get results that are less than 100, rather than inputs less than 100.

Comment: What is the point? Or is it just curiosity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general case what you're looking for is take-while.
Unfortunately, it has no default implementation in Java 8 streams.
See a [question about take-while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/java-8-limit-infinite-stream-by-a-predicate).

Comment: `takeWhile` was added in Java 9.

Answer (score -2):

If all you're looking to do is convert the given sequence into the triangle (as you describe), this does it much simpler.

```
List<Integer> l = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
            .mapToObj(n -> (n*n + n) / 2)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the primitive stream wrappers need an extra step to up-convert to objects, hence the `mapToObj` method.

If you're looking to stop filtering when you hit 100, easiest way I can think of is

```
    IntFunction<Integer> calc =n -> (n*n+n) / 2; 
    List<Integer> l = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
            .filter(n -> calc.apply(n) < 100)
            .mapToObj(calc)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Based on the changes to your question, I think this is also pretty important to point out.  If you want to mirror what you used to do, that would look like this:

```
    List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>(100);
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).forEach(i -> {
        int tri =calc.apply(i);
        if(tri < 100) {
            results.add(tri);
        }
    });
```

It's worth pointing out that streams are not necessarily ordered (though the default implementation follows the iterator).  If this were converted to a parallel stream you would see the difference (and power of streams).  You can't break from the execution because then you're assuming a certain amount about the processing order.  By filtering early (in my second form) you'll ensure that you only end up with a result stream of 13 entries in it before the final calculation.  Take this parallel option as a note as well.

```
    List<Integer> l = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).parallel()
            .filter(n -> calc.apply(n) < 100)
            .mapToObj(calc)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You'll see they're still ordered, but the computation of them was done on multiple threads.

Comment: OP is asking how to stop streaming when value of `(n*n + n) / 2` will start to become greater than 100, because of hight amount of cases which will need to be filtered. So question is "if we know that values after some n-th value will not be needed how can we skip them".

Comment: Op hasn't responded to any questions yet.  It's not clear what he's asking for yet.

Comment: @JohnAment if it's not clear to you what the question is, that's a good reason not to answer.

Comment: Your solution is worse than the one of the OP: it performs the computation twice for every number leading to a result < 100: once to filter, and once to map.

Comment: Your updated code still will need to stream over all elements and do possibly expensive calculations. Actually it even needs to do them twice now. I don't know how it is improvement.

Comment: No one has ever said that a stream is always faster than code build from before streams.

Comment: @JohnAment that's not the problem here. Your code, using streams, is slower than the OP's code, also using streams, and it doesn't do what the OP wants: stop iterating and doing the computations as soon as a result >= 100 is found.