# Implementing custom intermediate operations on Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to work out how to implement a custom intermediate operation on a Java 8 Stream. And it seems that I'm locked out :(

Specifically I want to take a stream and return every entry up to *and including* the first one that has a particular value. And I want to stop generating any after that - making it short-circuiting.

It's running a series of validation checks on input data. I want to stop on the first Error, if there is one, but I want to collate Warnings on the way. And because these validation checks might be expensive - involving database lookups, for example - I want to only run the minimum set needed.

So the code would be something like:

```
Optional<ValidationResult> result = validators.stream()
    .map(validator -> validator.validate(data))
    .takeUntil(result -> result.isError()) // This is the bit I can't do
    .reduce(new ValidationResult(), ::mergeResults);
```

It *seems* that I should be able to do something with ReferencePipeline.StatefulOp, except that it's all package scope and so I can't extend it. And so I'm wondering what the correct way to achieve this is? Or if it's even possible?

Note as well - this needs to be in Java 8, and not 9+ since we're not there yet for various unrelated reasons.

Cheers

Comment: Looking for `takeWhile` in Java-9?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765715/9662601) answer will help you creating your own `takeWhile()` in Java 8.

Comment: What values do you have in `ValidationResult` ? Is it possible to ignore its fields & only care about `isError` and which validators are left? If so check my answer...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290278/picking-elements-of-a-list-until-condition-is-met-with-java-8-lambdas/32291089#32291089 this seems to be what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Naman `takeWhile` would not work because of the *and including* part of the question

Comment: Did you check any of the answers? I had an answer with a different approach, I'd love to hear your feedback on that!

Answer (score 3):

Generally, custom operations will need to deal with the `Spliterator` interface. It extends the concept of the `Iterator` by adding characteristics and size information and the ability to split off a part of the elements as another spliterator (hence its name). It also simplifies the iteration logic by only needing one method.

```
public static <T> Stream<T> takeWhile(Stream<T> s, Predicate<? super T> condition) {
    boolean parallel = s.isParallel();
    Spliterator<T> spliterator = s.spliterator();
    return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(
        spliterator.estimateSize(),
        spliterator.characteristics()&~(Spliterator.SIZED|Spliterator.SUBSIZED)) {
            boolean active = true;
            Consumer<? super T> current;
            Consumer<T> adapter = t -> {
                if((active = condition.test(t))) current.accept(t);
            };

            @Override
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
                if(!active) return false;
                current = action;
                try {
                    return spliterator.tryAdvance(adapter) && active;
                }
                finally {
                    current = null;
                }
            }
        }, parallel).onClose(s::close);
}
```

To keep the stream’s properties, we query the parallel status first, to reestablish it for the new stream. Also, we register a close action that will close the original stream.

The main work is to implement a `Spliterator` decorating the previous stream state’s spliterator.

The characteristics are kept, except for the `SIZED` and `SUBSIZED`, as our operation results in an unpredictable size. The original size is still passed through, it will now be used as an estimate.

This solution stores the `Consumer` passed to `tryAdvance` for the duration of the operation, to be able to use the same adapter consumer, avoiding to create a new one for each iteration. This works, as it is guaranteed that `tryAdvance` is never invoked concurrently.

Parallelism is done via splitting, which is inherited from `AbstractSpliterator`. This inherited implementation will buffer some elements, which is reasonable, as implementing a better strategy for an operation like `takeWhile` is really complicated.

So you can use it like

```
    takeWhile(Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz", "hello", "world"), s -> s.length() == 3)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

which will print

```
foo
bar
baz
```

or

```
takeWhile(Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz", "hello", "world")
    .peek(s -> System.out.println("before takeWhile: "+s)), s -> s.length() == 3)
    .peek(s -> System.out.println("after takeWhile: "+s))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

which will print

```
before takeWhile: foo
after takeWhile: foo
foo
before takeWhile: bar
after takeWhile: bar
bar
before takeWhile: baz
after takeWhile: baz
baz
before takeWhile: hello
```

which shows that it does not process more than necessary. Before the `takeWhile` stage, we have to encounter the first non-matching element, after that, we only encounter the elements up to that.

Comment: `Spliterator` is a perfect example of how badly broken the Java streams design is.  You want a simple streams "intermediate operation" like, say, filtering away null elements of a stream? You get your choice of using `mapMulti` - and good luck reading that inline in your stream pipeline! - _or_ you can implement it reusably with _this_ monstrosity! _Everyone_ has to deal with the super-duper ability to _split_ streams for parallelism even though that's a feature not needed - or _wanted_ - in 98.5% of use cases. Compare to implementing same thing in C# LINQ w/ extension methods. Good job, Java!

Comment: @davidbak you “filter away null elements of a stream” using `.filter(x -> x != null)` or `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` if you prefer. There is no need to implement custom processing for such a trivial task.

Comment: @davidbak `mapMulti` is just an optimization for `flatMap` with a low number of elements. Before JDK 16 introduced it, you didn’t even know that you “need `mapMulti`”. That’s just another discussion around contrived scenarios. If you think, C# is great, fine, use C#, be happy, and stop bothering me with your rants.

Answer (score 1):

I admit that code wise, Holger's answer is a lot more sexy, but may be this is somehow easier to read:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> takeUntilIncluding(Stream<T> s, Predicate<? super T> condition) {

    class Box implements Consumer<T> {

        boolean stop = false;

        T t;

        @Override
        public void accept(T t) {
            this.t = t;
        }
    }

    Box box = new Box();

    Spliterator<T> original = s.spliterator();

    return StreamSupport.stream(new AbstractSpliterator<>(
        original.estimateSize(),
        original.characteristics() & ~(Spliterator.SIZED | Spliterator.SUBSIZED)) {

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {

            if (!box.stop && original.tryAdvance(box) && condition.test(box.t)) {
                action.accept(box.t);
                return true;
            }

            box.stop = true;

            return false;
        }
    }, s.isParallel());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a trick:

```
List<ValidationResult> res = new ArrayList<>(); // Can modify it with your `mergeResults` instead of list

Optional<ValidationResult> result = validators.stream()
    .map(validator -> validator.validate(data))
    .map(v -> {
       res.add(v);
       return v;
    })
    .filter(result -> result.isError())
    .findFirst();
```

The `List<ValidationResult> res` will contains your interested values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following structure;

```
AtomicBoolean gateKeeper = new AtomicBoolean(true);    
Optional<Foo> result = validators.stream()
    .filter(validator -> gateKeeper.get() 
                && gateKeeper.compareAndSet(true, !validator.validate(data).isError()) 
                && gateKeeper.get())
    .reduce(...) //have the first n non-error validators here
```

The filter with `gateKeeper` acts as an short circuiting logic and keeps going until it encounters the first `isError() == true` case, rejects it, & then shuts the doors for other `validate()` calls from then on. It looks a bit crazy, but it is much simpler than other *custom* implementations & might work perfectly if it suits your requirement.

Not 100% sure if this is helpful since I ignore the result of `validator.validate(data)` apart from `isError()` result, and the fact that it belongs to whichever `validator` in the list.