# How to get first n elements from a list whose some is below a given number in java 8?

Tags: loops, stream

how to re write following java legacy code in java 8

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(10,20,1,30,40,50);
    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    int sum = 0;
    for(int number :list) {
        sum = sum+number;
        if(sum>60) {
            break;
        }
        newList.add(number);
    }
```

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but closing related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32290278/2422776

Comment: But that is not at all answer for this :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works in Java 8 already, but I use

```
productItems.stream().limit(4).collect(Collectors.toList())
```