# Wrap pagination into Stream at run-time

Tags: java, pagination, java-stream, lazy-evaluation

Here is an example:

There are several services that return set of items as a page:

```
public Page<User> users(int offset, int limit);
public Page<Group> groups(int offset, int limit);
```

Consumers of such services implement the logic to handle the pagination on their side. It is not complicated, but still error-prone and time-consuming handling.

I try to wrap this logic inside:

```
public <T> Stream<T> streamOf(final BiFunction<Integer, Integer, PageResource<T>> pageResourceFunction);
```

The `pageResourceFunction` accepts `offset` and `limit` as input parameters, returns the page of elements.

A consumer should get a stream as:

```
Stream<User> users = streamOf(service::users);
```

**The real users are not loaded yet. They should be loaded only, when the consumer starts iteration via stream.**

1. Is it possible in Java? To construct a stream lazily (to return it from `streamOf`) with the number of streams/elements that is not known in advance?
2. If the 1st opiton is not possible, I can simplify a task a bit. Quite often `Page` contains the total number of elements, so I can in the `streamOf` get the first page, identify the total number of elements and calculate how many pages exist. But even this simplificaton does not help me to implement `streamOf`

Answer (score 3):

You can make `Stream`s with unknown size, but you have to know when the last element has been reached. This can be done in multiple ways by the user, but for this example I assume the user's implementation of `pageResourceFunction` will return `null` if the offset is past the last element.

### Java 9 and up

Java 9 introduced `Stream.takeWhile(Predicate)`, which will short-circuit the `Stream` when an element does not match the `Predicate`. In this solution, we want to take pages from the `pageResourceFunction` while it does not return `null`. We apply `takeWhile` to an infinite `Stream` of `offset`s that generate the required pages:

```
private static final int LIMIT = 4;

public static <T> Stream<T> streamOf(final BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Page<T>> pageResourceFunction) {
    return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + LIMIT)  // Creates an infinite Stream with elements 0, 4, 8, 12, ...
            .mapToObj(offset -> pageResourceFunction.apply(offset, LIMIT))
            .takeWhile(Objects::nonNull)
            .flatMap(page -> page.getElements().stream());
}
```

### Java 8

In Java 8 we have to make our own `Iterator` or `Spliterator` that takes elements while the `pageResourceFunction` does not return `null`, then wrap it into a `Stream` using `StreamSupport`. Reproducing `Stream.takeWhile` in Java 8 has been answered before in the questions below, but I will also provide my implementation:

- [Limit a stream by a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate)
- [Picking elements of a list until condition is met with Java 8 Lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290278/picking-elements-of-a-list-until-condition-is-met-with-java-8-lambdas)

I will use the `Spliterator` for this example, since it provides the `Stream` with more hints on how to optimize its execution with methods like `Spliterator.characteristics()`: The `Spliterator` will advance over the `Page`s from `pageResourceFunction` until the `pageResourceFunction` returns `null`.

Finally, the `Spliterator` is wrapped into a `Stream` using `StreamSupport.stream(Spliterator, boolean)`. Streams are always lazily-evaluated and are only fully evaluated when a terminal operation is called (for example `Stream.collect()`).

```
import lombok.Value;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class PageProviderJava8 {

    private static final int LIMIT = 4;

    public static <T> Stream<T> streamOf(final BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Page<T>> pageResourceFunction) {
        class PageSpliterator implements Spliterator<Page<T>> {

            private int offset = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Page<T>> action) {
                Page<T> page = pageResourceFunction.apply(offset, LIMIT);
                if (page == null) {
                    return false; // Last page is reached, stop the Spliterator
                }
                offset += LIMIT;
                action.accept(page);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public Spliterator<Page<T>> trySplit() {
                return null; // Should return non-null values if you want to use parallel streams
            }

            @Override
            public long estimateSize() {
                return Long.MAX_VALUE; // The size is unknown, so we return Long.MAX_VALUE
            }

            /*
             * Must be ordered, otherwise elements are requested from multiple pages,
             * which this Spliterator does not support.
             * Other characteristics depend on the implementation of Page.elements
             */
            @Override
            public int characteristics() {
                return ORDERED;
            }
        }

        return StreamSupport.stream(new PageSpliterator(), false)
                .flatMap(page -> page.getElements().stream());
    }

    // POJOs
    @Value
    public static class Page<T> {
        Collection<T> elements;
    }

    @Value
    public static class User {
        int id;
    }

    public static class PageProviderJava8Test {

        // Creates a Page of Users with ids offset to offset + limit. Will return null after 20 Users.
        public static Page<User> users(int offset, int limit) {
            if (offset >= 20) {
                return null;
            }
            Collection<User> elements = IntStream.range(offset, offset + limit)
                    .mapToObj(User::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new Page<>(elements);
        }

        @Test
        public void testPages() {
            List<User> users = PageProviderJava8.streamOf(PageProviderJava8Test::users)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            Assertions.assertThat(users)
                    .hasSize(20);
            Assertions.assertThat(users.get(0).getId()).isEqualTo(0);
            Assertions.assertThat(users.get(19).getId()).isEqualTo(19);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for option #2, for the 1st option, could not find one.

Hope it will be usefull for someone.

```
  private static final int LIMIT = 5;

  public <T> Stream<T> streamOf(final BiFunction<Integer, Integer, PageResource<T>> pageResourceFunction) {

    PageResource<T> firstPage = pageResourceFunction.apply(0, LIMIT);

    return Stream.concat(
      firstPage.getContent().stream(),
      IntStream.range(1, numberOfPages(firstPage.getTotalElements()))
      .mapToObj(numberOfPage ->
        pageResourceFunction.apply(
          numberOfPage * LIMIT, LIMIT))
      .map(PageResource::items)
      .flatMap(List::stream));
  }

  private int numberOfPages(final long total) {
    return (total % LIMIT == 0)
      ? (int) total / LIMIT
      : (int) total / LIMIT + 1;
  }
```

Assume the original page resource function accepts additional arguments:

```
  PageResource<Node> subNodes(
    final int parentId,
    final int someAdditionalId,
    final int offset,
    final int limit);
```

Consumer:

```
Stream<Node> stream = streamOf((offset, limit) -> 
  service.subNodes(111, 222, offset, limit));
```