# How to generate IntStream using java stream API

Tags: java, loops, java-8, java-stream

How I can replace this code with new Java Stream API:

```
int n = someFunction();    // n > 0
for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2)
    System.out.print(i);
```

I have tried to using `IntStream.iterate(3, i -> i + 2)`, but I can't add stop condition.

As I understand I can't use `.limit(int)` method here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`limit(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#limit-long-): you would have to determine how many elements are going to be between 3 and `sqrt(n)` by steps of 2. There are exactly `(sqrt(n) - 3) / 2 + 1` elements, so you could write:

```
IntStream.iterate(3, i -> i + 2).limit((int) (Math.sqrt(n) - 3) / 2 + 1);
```

Having said that, you could also create a closed range from 3 to `sqrt(n)` and filter out the even values, like this:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(3, (int) Math.sqrt(n)).filter(i -> i % 2 > 0)
```

Comment: Apparently this problem will be solved in Java 9:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate

Comment: The range version will also give you much better parallel behavior (for two reasons; parallel limit is expensive, and iterate() is a fundamentally sequential way to generate a stream source.)

Answer (score 3):

Using my free [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library two more solutions are possible in addition to ones proposed in @Tunaki answer.

1. Using backport of [`takeWhile`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/IntStreamEx.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.IntPredicate-) method which appears in JDK-9:

   ```
   IntStream is = IntStreamEx.iterate(3, i -> i + 2).takeWhile(i -> i*i <= n);
   ```
2. Using three-argument [`IntStreamEx.rangeClosed`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/IntStreamEx.html#rangeClosed-int-int-int-) which allows to specify the step:

   ```
   IntStream is = IntStreamEx.rangeClosed(3, (int) Math.sqrt(n), 2);
   ```