# Count regex matches with streams

Tags: java, regex, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to count the number of matches of a regex pattern with a simple Java 8 lambdas/streams based solution. For example for this pattern/matcher :

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("1,2,3,4");
```

There is the method `splitAsStream` which splits the text on the given pattern instead of matching the pattern. Although it's elegant and preserves immutability, it's not always correct :

```
// count is 4, correct
final long count = pattern.splitAsStream("1,2,3,4").count();

// count is 0, wrong
final long count = pattern.splitAsStream("1").count();
```

I also tried (ab)using an `IntStream`. The problem is I have to guess how many times I should call `matcher.find()` instead of until it returns false.

```
final long count = IntStream
        .iterate(0, i -> matcher.find() ? 1 : 0)
        .limit(100)
        .sum();
```

I am familiar with the traditional solution `while (matcher.find()) count++;` where `count` is mutable. Is there a simple way to do that with Java 8 lambdas/streams ?

Comment: Try to look into `takeWhile`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20765715/1743880

Comment: Splitting != matching. That's why you're getting odd numbers. You should negate your Pattern in order to retrieve the numbers and get what you want.

Comment: @Tunaki `takeWhile` looks quite interesting. But it will be available in Java 9 apparently, not Java 8.

Comment: @Flown I know what `splitAsStream` does and why it doesn't work the way I use it. I just tried your suggestion to negate the pattern and I was surprised to see correct results both for `"1,2,3,4"` and `"1"`. Would you like to post an answer ?

Comment: In Java-9: `matcher.results().count();`

Comment: @Tagir That would be perfect but it's Java 9. I am stuck with while loops until then as I can't get Flown's solution to work for every case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the `Pattern::splitAsStream` properly you have to invert your regex. That means instead of having `\\d+`(which would split on every number) you should use `\\D+`. This gives you ever number in your String.

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\D+");
// count is 4
long count = pattern.splitAsStream("1,2,3,4").count();
// count is 1
count = pattern.splitAsStream("1").count();
```

Comment: This is the "*simple*" solution I was looking for! But I prefer to negate the pattern like this `"(?:\\d+)"` as it is easier/feasible to negate any other pattern not just integers.

Comment: Doesn't always work though. For this input `"a 2"` the count is 2 instead of 1

Comment: Java 9 has the straight-forward solution `Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher("1,2,3,4").results().count()`…

Comment: Is there a more general solution? I have a long regex string which doesn't just match numbers..

Comment: @JennaKwon Depends on your use case

Answer (score 3):

The rather contrived language in the javadoc of [Pattern.splitAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-) is probably to blame.

> The stream returned by this method contains **each substring** of the input sequence that is **terminated by another subsequence that matches this pattern** or is terminated by the end of the input sequence.

If you print out all of the matches of `1,2,3,4` you may be surprised to notice that it is actually returning the **commas**, not the numbers.

```
    System.out.println("[" + pattern.splitAsStream("1,2,3,4")
            .collect(Collectors.joining("!")) + "]");
```

prints `[!,!,!,]`. The odd bit is why it is giving you `4` and not `3`.

Obviously this also explains why `"1"` gives `0` because there are no strings **between** numbers in the string.

A quick demo:

```
private void test(Pattern pattern, String s) {
    System.out.println(s + "-[" + pattern.splitAsStream(s)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("!")) + "]");
}

public void test() {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    test(pattern, "1,2,3,4");
    test(pattern, "a1b2c3d4e");
    test(pattern, "1");
}
```

prints

```
1,2,3,4-[!,!,!,]
a1b2c3d4e-[a!b!c!d!e]
1-[]
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually know what `splitAsStream` does and why it doesn't work the way I use it. I still don't know how to count matches. Nevertheless, your answer is quite informative and well written so you get a +1.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend [`AbstractSpliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#tryAdvance-java.util.function.Consumer-) to solve this:

```
static class SpliterMatcher extends AbstractSpliterator<Integer> {
    private final Matcher m;

    public SpliterMatcher(Matcher m) {
        super(Long.MAX_VALUE, NONNULL | IMMUTABLE);
        this.m = m;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Integer> action) {
        boolean found = m.find();
        if (found)
            action.accept(m.groupCount());
        return found;
    }
}

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("1");
long count = StreamSupport.stream(new SpliterMatcher(matcher), false).count();
System.out.println("Count: " + count); // 1

matcher = pattern.matcher("1,2,3,4");
count = StreamSupport.stream(new SpliterMatcher(matcher), false).count();
System.out.println("Count: " + count); // 4


matcher = pattern.matcher("foobar");
count = StreamSupport.stream(new SpliterMatcher(matcher), false).count();
System.out.println("Count: " + count); // 0
```

Comment: I just tried that and it does produce correct results. It's also very informative! I am not sure it qualifies as a "*simple*" solution! Then I guess, I only have to write `SpliterMatcher` once and reuse it with different matchers.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with creating a new spliterator for each stream—that's what always happens behind the scenes anyway. It’s also the straight forward way of implementing a not yet existing kind of stream and in this regard, it *is* simple, it consist of a single class containing one concrete method and a single delegate object. How much simpler can it be? But when you stream over integers instead of `MatchResult`s, it’s more efficient to implement `Spliterator.OfInt` instead of `Spliterator<Integer>` and create an `IntStream`. And to ensure reusability, it should report `ORDERED`…

Comment: And I recommend overriding `forEachRemaining`, if there is a simple, straight-forward implementation possible (as it is the case here).

Answer (score 1):

Shortly, you have a `stream of String` and a `String pattern` : how many of those strings match with this pattern ?

```
final String myString = "1,2,3,4";
Long count = Arrays.stream(myString.split(","))
      .filter(str -> str.matches("\\d+"))
      .count();
```

where first line can be another way to stream `List<String>().stream()`, `...`

Am I wrong ?

Comment: This requires 2 different regex patterns. 1 for the delimiter and 1 to match data. I would like to avoid that. Otherwise it produces correct results.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 9

You may use [`Matcher#results()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) to get hold of all matches:

> `Stream<MatchResult>`      `results()`
> *Returns **a stream of match results for each subsequence** of the input sequence that matches the pattern. The match results occur in the same order as the matching subsequences in the input sequence.*

## Java 8 and lower

Another simple solution based on using a reverse pattern:

```
String pattern = "\\D+";
System.out.println("1".replaceAll("^" + pattern + "|" + pattern + "$", "").split(pattern, 0).length); // => 1
```

Here, all non-digits are removed from the start and end of a string, and then the string is split by non-digit sequences without reporting any empty trailing whitespace elements (since `0` is passed as a *limit* argument to `split`).

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/luHaAs):

```
String pattern = "\\D+";
System.out.println("1".replaceAll("^" + pattern + "|" + pattern + "$", "").split(pattern, 0).length);    // => 1
System.out.println("1,2,3".replaceAll("^" + pattern + "|" + pattern + "$", "").split(pattern, 0).length);// => 3
System.out.println("hz 1".replaceAll("^" + pattern + "|" + pattern + "$", "").split(pattern, 0).length); // => 1
System.out.println("1 hz".replaceAll("^" + pattern + "|" + pattern + "$", "").split(pattern, 0).length); // => 1
System.out.println("xxx 1 223 zzz".replaceAll("^" + pattern + "|" + pattern + "$", "").split(pattern, 0).length);//=>2
```