# Java 8 stream short circuit manually

Tags: performance, java-8, java-stream, short-circuiting

Is there any way to manually short circuit a stream (like in findFirst)?

**Example:**

Imagine a huge dictionary ordered by word size and alphabet:

```
cat
... (many more)
lamp
mountain
... (many more)
```

Only ready and compute the file from beginning, *return immediately* when line size exceeds 4:

```
read cat, compute cat
...
read tree, compute lamp
read mountain, return
```

The following code is very concise but does not take into advantage the order of the stream, it has to ready every line:

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(DICTIONARY_PATH))) {
        return lines
                // filter for words with the correct size
                .filter(line -> line.length() == 4)
                // do stuff...
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate

Comment: What you want is generally called `takewhile`. According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate) it seems like there is no built-in way to do that, but you can write one yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer based on [Limit a stream by a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate), processing correctly stops when predicate returns false. Hopefully this method comes available in [Java 9](https://jaxenter.com/java-9-features-developers-yearning-112783.html):

```
private static List<String> getPossibleAnswers(int numberOfChars, char[][] possibleChars) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(DICTIONARY_PATH)) {
        return takeWhile(lines, line -> line.length() <= numberOfChars)
                // filter length
                .filter(line -> line.length() == numberOfChars)
                // do stuff
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

static <T> Spliterator<T> takeWhile(Spliterator<T> splitr, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    return new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(splitr.estimateSize(), 0) {              boolean stillGoing = true;

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
            if (stillGoing) {
                boolean hadNext = splitr.tryAdvance(elem -> {
                    if (predicate.test(elem)) {
                        consumer.accept(elem);
                    } else {
                        stillGoing = false;
                    }
                });
                return hadNext && stillGoing;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}

static <T> Stream<T> takeWhile(Stream<T> stream, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(takeWhile(stream.spliterator(), predicate), false);
}
```

Comment: This is quite inefficient when compared to a classical loop.

Comment: @aventurin there might be a faster implementation with java9. At least the code is concise, no need for temporary variables.

Comment: The stream API might hide the bloat behind it from the programmer, but there's no magic that can reduce the number of CPU cycles, memory reallocations (ArrayList-collector) or extra object and class creation. Besides that, the equivalent code using a loop is easier to understand and takes just three lines of code plus two variable definitions.

Comment: @aventurin That's not the point of the question. However, the problem statement of my example is bigger. I was first coding it with while-loops and then switched to streams because I wanted to increase my knowledge about them. Implicit version: https://github.com/Journeycorner/tom-turbo-solver/commit/7607a90a5e1ecc5cae054ae8b19b1ecc313ab580 vs. functional version: https://github.com/Journeycorner/tom-turbo-solver/blob/master/src/at/journeycorner/Main.java . If you can code it with less lines of code, without omitting brackets, write me a pull request ;).