# Java8, convert for loop with a condition to lambda

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, java-8

Java 8.

Converting a forEach loop into a lambda expression is understood, at least for me.
Converting a for loop based with a condition, in the other hand, isn't.

If it's possible ,my question would be:
 how can you convert the following for loop into a lambda expression

```
List<Field> fields = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Class<?> c = this.getClass(); c != null; c = c.getSuperclass())
            Collections.addAll(fields, c.getDeclaredFields());
```

Many thanks in advance,

~Ben.

Comment: Lambda isn't going to help you here. If you want to get all fields of class including inherited, try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042798/retrieving-the-inherited-attribute-names-values-using-java-reflection

Comment: I disagree with the accepted answer that recursion is the better approach, second my inductive code works better.

Comment: `Stream` s direct replacement for **for-each** style. But here, you can't either flatten the stream, what you need is iterate over the stream by yourself. Which means, internal iteration will not help you.

Comment: I would love to know if my question is even possible

Comment: Yes, you can alternatively use `while` loop, while `c.getSuperclass()` is not null. But anyway streams and lambdas are not going to help you here.

Comment: I would like to focus more on functional programming @esin88

Comment: Related: [Streaming a class hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40240450/2711488)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there is a way, but it needs `takeWhile` that it is in jdk-9.

I'm doing a mapping here to get the names of the fields. You would have to add a `@SuppressWarnings("null")` to the method.

```
System.out.println(Stream.iterate(this.getClass(), (Class<?> x) -> x.getSuperclass())
            .takeWhile(x -> x != null)
            .flatMap(c -> Arrays.stream(c.getDeclaredFields()))
            .map(c -> c.getName())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

jdk-9 also introduces a `Stream.iterate` that acts like an Iterator with `seed, hasNext, next` that is far more suited for your case.

You **could use** StreamEx library for this btw:

```
 StreamEx.of(Stream.iterate(this.getClass(), (Class<?> x) -> x.getSuperclass()))
            .takeWhile(x -> x != null)
            .flatMap(c -> Arrays.stream(c.getDeclaredFields()))
            .map(c -> c.getName())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**And with new iterate method**:

```
 Stream.iterate(this.getClass(), c -> c != null, (Class<?> c) -> c.getSuperclass())
            .flatMap(c -> Arrays.stream(c.getDeclaredFields()))
            .map(c -> c.getName())
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Stream.iterate(this.getClass(), c -> c != null, (Class<?> c) -> c.getSuperclass())
            .flatMap(c -> Arrays.stream(c.getDeclaredFields()))
            .map(c -> c.getName())
            .collect(Collectors.toList())

Comment: is it only possible with java9 ?

Comment: @Benma you need `takeWhile` for it to work in jdk-8. This is either in `StreamEx` library or you can add it yourself until available from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate

Comment: @Roland indeed, a Stream out of the Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want to work with streams. Open a stream on your list and simply use filter. Filter takes a FunctionalInterface/Lambda-expression.

Comment: I'm well familiar with streams and filters, but to implement the following loop condition with these methods isn't straightforward to me for some reason, is there any chance for a code snippet?