# IntStream iterate in steps

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

How do you iterate through a range of numbers (0-100) in steps(3) with IntStream?

I tried `iterate`, but this never stops executing.

```
IntStream.iterate(0, n -> n + 3).filter(x -> x > 0 && x < 100).forEach(System.out::println)
```

Comment: didn't understand why you ask and answer in the same time ?!?

Comment: @YagamiLight I couldn't find this answer on stackoverflow. Just want to help others and expand the knowledge base. And maybe others have a higher performing solution, since my answer is not 'ideal'.

Comment: i totally understand and really like this why of thinking but you could ask to improve your answer (by adding it in the question) or simplly wait a littble bit longer

Comment: The filter() method, if not otherwise limited, will search through a whole collection (which in your case is effectively infinite). What you're looking for is a takeWhile() method (that iterates only up to a first element that falsifies a predicate). Look for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually `range` is ideal for this.

```
IntStream.range(0, 100).filter(x -> x % 3 == 0); //107,566 ns/op [Average]
```

---

Edit: Holgers's solution is the fastest performing solution.

Since the following lines of code

```
IntStream.range(0, 100).filter(x -> x % 3 == 0).forEach((x) -> x = x + 2); 

IntStream.range(0, 100 / 3).map(x -> x * 3).forEach((x) -> x = x + 2); 

int limit = ( 100 / 3 ) + 1; 
IntStream.iterate(0, n -> n + 3).limit(limit).forEach((x) -> x = x + 2);
```

show these benchmark results

```
Benchmark                 Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
Benchmark.intStreamTest   avgt    5  485,473 ± 58,402  ns/op
Benchmark.intStreamTest2  avgt    5  202,135 ±  7,237  ns/op
Benchmark.intStreamTest3  avgt    5  280,307 ± 41,772  ns/op
```

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, 100/3).map(i -> i*3)` might be more efficient…

Comment: @Holger Awesome, your solution performs 2,4 times higher!

Comment: Well, 33 multiplications *should* be faster than 100 modulo operations. But note that when benchmarking, you have to care that the JIT can’t optimize the consumer to a no-op, i.e. if you use JMH, call `BlackHole.consume` with the `x` in the consumer.

Comment: What if we need range 900 to 1900 with step 5

Answer (score 16):

Actually you can also achieve the same results with a combination of peek and allMatch:

```
IntStream.iterate(0, n -> n + 3).peek(n -> System.out.printf("%d,", n)).allMatch(n -> n < 100 - 3);
```

This prints

> 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99,

But nevertheless, this one is faster:

```
IntStream.range(0, 100 / 3 + 1).map(x -> x * 3).forEach((x) -> System.out.printf("%d,", x));
```

### Java 9 Update:

Now the same iteration easier to achieve with Java 9:

```
Stream.iterate(0, i -> i <= 100, i -> 3 + i).forEach(i -> System.out.printf("%d,", i));
```

Comment: how do you get rid of the last comma in the printout using the same code?

Comment: @leeCoder Something like: `String joined = IntStream.range(0, 100 / 3 + 1).map(x -> x * 3).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));`

Answer (score 8):

In JDK9 there's `takeWhile` [1](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```
IntStream
  .iterate(0, n -> n + 3)
  .takeWhile(n -> n < 100)
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 6):

`limit` can also be used

```
int limit = ( 100 / 3 ) + 1;
IntStream.iterate(0, n -> n + 3).limit(limit).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 5):

Elegant Solution:

```
IntStream.iterate(0, n -> n < 100, n -> n + 3).forEach(System.out::println)
```

Stream.iterate() supports a *hasNext()* **predicate** (added in Java 9) which can be used to limit the stream in more natural way.

Comment: Already mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44761829/1553851).

Answer (score 3):

If you are ok adding a library dependency, the [`IntInterval`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/list/primitive/IntInterval.html) class in [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) has the step function I think you are looking for.  I tried a few different approaches converting `IntInterval` to an `IntStream`, since the original question asked for `IntStream`.  Here are the solutions I came up with using `IntInterval` and then converting it to an `IntStream`.

```
IntInterval interval = IntInterval.zeroTo(99).by(3);
interval.each(System.out::print);

IntStream.of(interval.toArray()).forEach(System.out::print);

IntStream.Builder builder = IntStream.builder();
interval.each(builder::add);
builder.build().forEach(System.out::print);

IntStream.generate(interval.intIterator()::next)
    .limit(interval.size()).forEach(System.out::print);
```

`IntInterval` is inclusive on the from and to like `IntStream.rangeClosed()`.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 2):

More generic solution:

```
LongStream.range(0L, (to - from) / step) // +1 depends on inclusve or exclusive
                .mapToObj(i -> (from + i * step))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```