# How to add sequential elements to a List with streams

Tags: java, list, java-stream

Have this:

```
    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < upperBound; i += step) {
        list.add(i);
    }
```

How can I replace it with functional styled streams?

thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Is there a logic behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop looks fine.

If you absolutely want to use a stream, you can create an `IntStream` and box it into a `List`. For example:

```
int elementCount = upperBound / step;
if (upperBound % step != 0) elementCount++;

List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, elementCount)
         .map(i -> i * step)
         .boxed()
         .collect(toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

Note that defining the upper bound is not straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `range` function in `IntStream` :

```
List<Integer> collect = IntStream.range(startRange, upperBound).filter(x -> (x % step) == 0).boxed().collect(toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

You can find more information in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358827/intstream-iterate-in-steps)