# Limit IntStream.iterate to a specific value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm generating, let's say, the following range:

```
IntStream.iterate(1, i -> 3*i)
```

How do I limit the stream to a specific element value e.g. 100 (not elements count with limit())?

Thank you!

**UPDATE** the function can be arbitrary

Comment: Look into this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358827/intstream-iterate-in-steps?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @surendrapanday the increment function is just an example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can’t use Java 9 yet, you can use the following reimplementation of the three-arg `IntStream.iterate`:

```
public static IntStream iterate(int seed, IntPredicate hasNext, IntUnaryOperator next) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(next); Objects.requireNonNull(hasNext);
    return StreamSupport.intStream(
        new Spliterators.AbstractIntSpliterator(
            Long.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED|Spliterator.NONNULL) {
        private IntUnaryOperator op = i -> { op = next; return i; };
        private int value = seed;

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(IntConsumer action) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(action);
            if(op == null) return false;
            int t = op.applyAsInt(value);
            if(!hasNext.test(t)) { op = null; return false; }
            action.accept(value = t);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void forEachRemaining(IntConsumer action) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(action);
            IntUnaryOperator first = op;
            if(first == null) return;
            op = null;
            for(int t = first.applyAsInt(value); hasNext.test(t); t = next.applyAsInt(t))
                action.accept(t);
        }
    }, false);
}
```

It works similar to Java 9’s `IntStream.iterate`, except that you have to change the class you’re invoking the `static` method on (or adapt the `import static` statement):

```
iterate(1, i -> i < 100, i -> i*3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
1
3
9
27
81
```

Comment: that is cool but woow.. so much code.. ok, I guess I will workaround it at least in my case at least unless I have Java 8

Answer (score 5):

A new method

```
Stream<T> iterate​(T seed,Predicate<? super T> hasNext,UnaryOperator<T> next)
```

was introduced in Java-9. So starting with that version it is possible to do something like this:

```
IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i < 100, i -> 3*i)
```

Which will produce `1 3 9 27 81`

Comment: ok, seems to be the thing I'm looking for. But what about Java 8?

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich: Java Stream API has been introduced in Java 8.

Comment: @Nikolas I mean this predicate `hasNext`

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich, the overloaded iterate method was added in Java-9

Comment: @Aominè, this will produce only `1 3 9 27 81`

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc , Dmitry Senkovich  Right I get the question now.

Comment: @Aominè might be just me, but whenever I end-up choosing `Stream#iterate` from java-9, probably time to write that as a loop, unless there are other operations that I would need like `filter, map` etc...

Comment: @Eugene, I agree. Developers often use `Stream#iterate` to iterate over an array or/and do some index manipulation. But `steam` isn't designed for this purpose. It can be done easily with a loop

Comment: @Eugene Agreed! indeed.

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc there is nothing wrong with using for example `IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < 100, i -> i + 1)` to index into an array or a list and do something with it, but in this case it would be _better_ to use `IntStream.range(0, 100)`. Nevertheless, I also agree that using an imperative loop for the aforementioned example would probably be better.

Comment: @Aominè depends on the operation. Even an operation as simple as `toArray()` may justify using a stream, as it eliminates the need for an allocation statement with a predicted size, as well as dealing with array indices.

Answer (score 5):

As addition to other answers, if you can use [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) already, there is another possibility using [**`Stream#takeWhile`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) taking a `Predicate` as parameter.

Tested in [jshell](/questions/tagged/jshell)

```
jshell> IntStream.iterate(1, i -> 3 * i).takeWhile(i -> i < 100).toArray();
$3 ==> int[5] { 1, 3, 9, 27, 81 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IntStream.range(0, N).forEach(this::doSomething);


int[] arr = IntStream.range(start, end).toArray();
```

Comment: the example was not about incrementing with 3 itself, there could be a random function. I need to limit the value

Comment: maybe I'm being too stupid, sorry:) But I don't understand you: the problem is that I don't know a limit (N in your case) but I have a function and an initial value