# How to implement a parallel supporting takeWhile for the Stream API in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've seen some `takeWhile` implementations for the Java 8 stream API but they all seem to turn the stream into a non-parallel stream. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765715/398441) one:

```
static <T> Spliterator<T> takeWhile(
    Spliterator<T> splitr, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
  return new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<T>(splitr.estimateSize(), 0) {
    boolean stillGoing = true;
    @Override public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
      if (stillGoing) {
        boolean hadNext = splitr.tryAdvance(elem -> {
          if (predicate.test(elem)) {
            consumer.accept(elem);
          } else {
            stillGoing = false;
          }
        });
        return hadNext && stillGoing;
      }
      return false;
    }
  };
}

static <T> Stream<T> takeWhile(Stream<T> stream, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
   return StreamSupport.stream(takeWhile(stream.spliterator(), predicate), false);
}
```

Here `StreamSupport.stream(takeWhile(stream.spliterator(), predicate), false);` turns the stream passed to `takeWhile` into a sequential stream. Is anyone aware of an implementation that supports parallel streams or how can I modify this code to make it maintain/support parallel streams?

Comment: You can't, really. Sorry, but you'll have to deal with that; it's really an inherently sequential operation.  You can use the default very limited parallelism that works with everything, which is what you'd get as a result of using `.parallel` on that stream, but that's as good as you can get.

Comment: In order to extract any real parallelism here, the predicate would have to be insanely expensive (e.g., trying to factor very large numbers).  It's not impossible, but it's pretty unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your source is known to be unordered, then the following implementation should work:

```
static final class UnorderedTakeWhileSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T>, Consumer<T>, Cloneable {
    private final Predicate<? super T> predicate;
    private final AtomicBoolean checked = new AtomicBoolean();
    private Spliterator<T> source;
    private T cur;

    UnorderedTakeWhileSpliterator(Spliterator<T> source, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(T t) {
        this.cur = t;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        if (!checked.get() && source.tryAdvance(this)) {
            if (predicate.test(cur)) {
                action.accept(cur);
                return true;
            } else {
                checked.set(true);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
        Spliterator<T> prefix = source.trySplit();
        if(prefix == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if(checked.get()) {
            return Spliterators.emptySpliterator();
        }
        UnorderedTakeWhileSpliterator<T> clone;
        try {
            clone = (UnorderedTakeWhileSpliterator<T>) clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new InternalError(e);
        }
        clone.source = prefix;
        return clone;
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return source.estimateSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return source.characteristics() & (DISTINCT | SORTED | NONNULL);
    }

    @Override
    public Comparator<? super T> getComparator() {
        return source.getComparator();
    }
}
```

Create the stream with the following method:

```
static <T> Stream<T> takeWhile(Stream<T> stream, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
   return StreamSupport.stream(UnorderedTakeWhileSpliterator<>(stream.spliterator(), predicate), stream.isParallel());
}
```

Ordered implementation would be much more tricky as it should buffer non-prefixed items and propagate the cancelling to the suffixes. Something like this is implemented in JDK-9 (not as spliterator, but as normal stream operation), but I doubt that even this tricky implementation wins in many cases over sequential stream.

Comment: Thanks but I don't seem to have a class named UnorderedTDOfRef? Where can I find this?

Comment: @Johan, fixed, sorry.

Comment: It works :) Off topic, but is this what you will include in the StreamEx library? That would be awesome!

Comment: @Johan, basically yes, I just need to extend it to `dropWhile` and `takeWhileInclusive` and write more tests.

Comment: This doesn’t look right to me. You are treating hitting the end the same way as a negative result from the predicate, in other words, once any of the spliterators hits its end, all others stop traversal.

Comment: @Holger, should be better now

Comment: I don’t think that it is a good idea to return an empty spliterator in `trySplit`. That may cause the caller to waste more resources in trying to actually process it. Denying the `split` in the `checked.get()` case is straight-forward (afaik, all other spliterators will also return `null` from `trySplit` when there are no more elements left). And you may do that check first, before attempting to split the source. Btw, I don’t think that using `clone` here has any benefit. Having a dedicate `private` constructor is much simpler…