# Java double stream filtering of sorted list

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Let T be a stream of doubles sorted in ascending order

in the following code, how can I make it such that the first time the filter is false that the rest of the elements are not tested? I need it to early-terminate the loop since due to the sorted list, none of the elements past the first filter failure will return false. I'd like to do it with streams instead of going back to a for loop

```
public final double λ(double t)
{
    return T.stream().filter(s -> s < t).map(s -> ψ(t - s)).sum();
}
```

Comment: Streams can't do this.  Sorry, but it's the truth.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate