# How to stop an infinite stream if you don't know the exact number of iterations in Java 8

Tags: java-8

What is the best way to transform a while loop like the one below to the functional stream if you don't know the exact number of iterations?

```
int i = 10;
while (i > 1) {
    System.out.println(i);
    i--;
}
```

I came up with something like this, but I want to remove the `limit` and stop iteration with something like a predicate condition

```
Stream.iterate(10, n -> n - 1).filter(n -> n > 1).limit(9).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: just a side note, to match the logic of your while loop, you should have used `forEachOrdered` and not `forEach`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`takeWhile`, since java-9 though:

```
 Stream.iterate(10, n -> n - 1) 
       .takeWhile(i -> i > 1)
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

See [a back port for java-8 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765715/1059372) also.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am trying to do this in java 8.

Comment: I can see it, but it doesn't look like a good refactoring to make the code more readable.

Comment: @Mark well, if you need this by a `Predicate`, you can't do it otherwise. `Stream::iterate` also has a method that acts like a for loop (and thus will work for your case) - but since 9 also...