# Java Streams Api, finite stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to create a fibonacci sequence through the usage of Java Streams API. I've create a supplier, but I want it to stop at a specific value (e.g 1000000).

The suplier:

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class FibonacciSupplier implements Supplier<Integer> {

    private int current;
    private int next;

    public FibonacciSupplier() {
        current = 0;
        next = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get() {
        int result = current;
        current = next + current;
        next = result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

How I would like it to be:

```
Stream.generate(new FibonacciSupplier()).maxValue(1000000);
```

The maxValue does not exist as a function, I'm using it as a name to for context.

Comment: Have you tried using an `if` statement? `if (value > 1000000) { dontDo(); }`?

Comment: `limit` might be what you need. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to use `takeWhile`, which is available in Java 9+:

```
Stream.generate(new FibonacciSupplier())
    .takeWhile(i -> i <= 1000000) //will stop stream when value exceeds given limit
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you're using Java 8, then you may want to look into [hacks for stopping an infinite stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate)

Comment: If you knew that question existed, why didn't you close this as a dupe?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `.limit()` method on the stream as below :

```
Stream.generate(new FibonacciSupplier()).limit(1000).forEach(System.out::println);
```

From the docs,

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, truncated
>   to be no longer than {@code maxSize} in length.

Comment: `takeWhile` from java9 will do the job

Comment: Eh... Yes and no. limit limits by the number of elements. He wants to stop once the sequence has exceeded a certain value. How do you know that a fib number of 1000000 is element 1000?