# Best way to read lines from file Java 8 and break in between

Tags: java, file, file-io, java-8, java-stream

The `Files.lines().forEach()` method doesn't allow the `break`. What's the optimal way to read lines in Java 8 in chunks and break when needed?

Update 1:  Example for exception.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try(IntStream s = IntStream.range(0, 5);){
    s.forEach(i -> validate(i));

    }catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Hello World!");    
    }
}
static void validate(int s){

    if(s > 1){            
        //throw new Exception(); ?
    }
    System.out.println(s);
} }
```

Comment: if you are using a `Stream`, the only way to break would be to throw an Exception; otherwise a for loop as it used to work for decades

Comment: Yeah, the for loop doesn't leverage any Java 8 features right? and where do I throw the exception?

Comment: What feature are you trying to leverage? Your example is not leveraging anything, that can't be easily done in a `for` loop.

Comment: `Files.lines().filter(<throw Exception under some condition>)` - once the Exception is thrown, catch it - and this will act as the `break`...

Comment: @Eugene Of course, that is using exception for flow control, which is an [anti-pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/189222/202153).

Comment: @Eugene doesn't the Files.lines() read all the lines into memory if the filter is applied?

Comment: @Andreas agreed, but how would you break from a Stream otherwise? at my workplace we choose a specific exception with no stack-traces

Comment: @A.Dev no it does not. don't confuse it with `readAllLine` and `lines`

Comment: @Eugene Why would I break from a stream? A stream is for processing all values independent of each other (filtered or not). Rather than trying to use an anti-pattern to force the use of a screwdriver as a hammer, perhaps re-thinking why the code has to use a stream is in order. I'm not saying that exception is not the right choice, *sometimes*, but streams is also not always the right choice. The language has multiple tools (features) that can do the job. A good programmer will use the *right* tool at the right time.

Comment: @Andreas well I am not the good programmers, in such a case. We use it for `reduce`, mainly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy by using java-9 `takeWhile`, So when the condition (s < 1) fails it will drop the remaining part of stream [here](https://blog.indrek.io/articles/whats-new-in-java-9-streams/)

> when an element is encountered that does not match the predicate, the rest of the stream is discarded.

```
s.takeWhile(s -> s < 1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

By using java-8 tried an example but this not every efficient as `takeWhile`, by combining `peek` and `findFirst()` but need to have double check condition which makes no sense rather than this i will prefer standard while loop

```
IntStream.range(0, 5).peek(i->{
         if(i<3) {
             System.out.println(i);
         }

     }).filter(j->j>=3).findFirst();
```

do the action in peek and stream will break when ever predicate validated in `findFirst`

Comment: Unfortunately these are added in jdk-9 @A.Dev

Comment: @A.Dev there is a back port for it for java-8... just search SO

Comment: i found this if it is helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate @A.Dev

Comment: Stream.allMatch() is probably the correct way. Any disadvantage with this?

Comment: check the update answer you can try that in java-8 using findFirst @A.Dev

Comment: @Deadpool I can also include my operations in the allMatch() predicate right? as a function

Comment: That is a short-circuiting terminal operation. that is not right place for operations @A.Dev

Comment: Not sure where the quoted part came in from. Yet, how does this relate to *breaking in chunks*?

Comment: If i understand the question he want to terminate the stream based on condition @nullpointer there is link the post of my answer

Comment: And my understanding is he want to teriminate but not breaking into chunks, correct me if i'm wrong sir @nullpointer