# How to stream over a range of BigIntegers?

Tags: java, java-stream, biginteger

Hello I currently have this piece of code for finding factorial which is work fine

```java
public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE; i.compareTo(n) <= 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        sum = sum.multiply(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

What I want to achieve is to convert this to a `Stream<BigInteger>` and write it like this

```java
public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    return getBigIntegerStream(n).reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply);
}
```

So my question is how I can get a `Stream<BigInteger>` similar to how I can declare an `IntStream`?

```java
IntStream.range(1, myInt);
```

Comment: Why? You could never compute n! for n larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: @JamesKPolk yes check my last comment on the accepted answer i will update my question, still the creation of a BigInteger stream is relative

Comment: Agreed, it is a good question in that regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
    return Stream.iterate (BigInteger.ONE, i -> i.add(BigInteger.ONE)).limit(Integer.parseInt(n.toString())).reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply);
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to limit the stream. Fixed now.

Of course it would be simpler to just accept an `int` (or a `long`) as the argument:

```
public static BigInteger factorial(int n) {
    return Stream.iterate (BigInteger.ONE, i -> i.add(BigInteger.ONE)).limit(n).reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply);
}
```

It is very unlikely you will even need to calculate the factorial of a number larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. The factorial of such a number would be huge, and would probably take very long to calculate.

EDIT: Not a proper benchmark, but `factorial(100000)` took me 5 seconds, and `factorial(1000000)` took 8 minutes. At this rate, `factorial(Long.MAX_VALUE)` or even `factorial(Integer.MAX_VAULE)` will take very very long time. Therefore I don't see the point of requiring a `BigInteger` argument.

Comment: This break on Integer.parseInt when biginteger is bigger that a regular int which is the reason i dont use integers

Comment: @PanosK Well, if you want to calculate the factorial of a number larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, you'll get into trouble, but I doubt you'll even need to calculate such a huge value.

Comment: you are correct i finally used the your second version no need for BigInteger input, thanks

Comment: It might be unlikely to ever want/need to calculate with more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements, but still, there is no reason to restrict the number to `int` when `limit` accepts a `long`. And instead of `Integer.parseInt(n.toString())` , we can use the much cheaper `n.longValueExact()`. Also keep in mind that summands can be swapped, so instead of `i -> i.add(BigInteger.ONE)` you can also use `BigInteger.ONE::add`. Starting with Java 9, we can use `Stream.iterate(BigInteger.ONE, bi -> bi.compareTo(n) < 0, BigInteger.ONE::add)` which supports value beyond `Long.MAX_VALUE`—in theory.

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent would be

```
Stream.iterate(BigInteger.ONE, i -> i.add(BigInteger.ONE))
    .takeWhile(i -> i.compareTo(end) < 0)
```

where `end` is a `BigInteger`.

`Stream.iterate` will create an infinite stream, starting from 1 and continually adding 1. `takeWhile` will stop the stream once the condition is met.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate

Comment: When using Java 9+, you can use `Stream.iterate(BigInteger.ONE, bi -> bi.compareTo(n) < 0, BigInteger.ONE::add)` in the first place instead of resorting to `takeWhile`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
public static BigInteger factorial(int n) 
{ 
  return IntStream.rangeClosed(1,n)
                  .mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
                  .reduce(BigInteger::multiply)
}
```