# Can I limit the Java Stream length by the total of int values that are field of items of the stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, limit

I know that `limit` method can limit the Java `Stream` **length** by specified value.

But is there a way to limit the `Stream` length by **the total of int values** that are field of items of the stream?

The stream is made from `List`.

The requirements are:

- The way needs to be able to execute processes **in parallel**
- The way needs to create `Stream` object.
- I prefer to use **Java8** if possible.

Now I implement it by the following way.

1. Use `for` statement and count the *total*.
2. And then `break` the `for` statement when the *total* reaches the *limit value*.

But this way cannot satisfy the requirements.

If `limitByTotalIntOf` method is given, the ideal way I want is:

```java
class Item { int value; }
List<Item> listOfItems = createListOfItems();

int limitValue = 10000;
listOfItems.parallelStream()
    .map(item -> /* set value */)
    .limitByTotalIntOf(limitValue, item -> item.value)
    .map(item -> /* do something */);
```

Current way is:

```java
int total = 0;
for(Item item: listOfItems) {
    int v = /* set value */;
    total += v;
    if(total < limitValue) break;
    /* do something */
}
```

Is there any way to satisfy the requirements?

Comment: take a look at `takeWhile` in Java-9

Comment: Do take a look at how to [Limit a stream by a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate)

Comment: Java9's `takeWhile` can perform in parallel but doesn't seem to qork correctly.

Comment: Java8's alternative `takeWhile` seems not parallel.

Comment: `if(total < limitValue) break;` looks strange. Did you mean `if(total >= limitValue) break;`?

Comment: I meant `total >= limitValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `/* do something */` is an expensive operation that truly benefits from parallel processing, the best solution is to separate the selection of the affected items from their actual processing.

The selection is best done sequentially, similar to the loop you already have:

```
List<Item> selectedItems = listOfItems;
int total = 0;
for(int ix = 0, num = listOfItems.size(); ix < num; ix++) {
    total += listOfItems.get(ix).getValue();
    if(total > limitValue) {
        selectedItems = listOfItems.subList(0, ix);
        break;
    }
}
selectedItems.parallelStream()
// your actual heavy operation
```

Note that, given the current implementation, a parallel stream over a sublist is way more efficient than using `limit(…)` on a parallel stream over the entire list.

---

The parallel stream processing works by splitting the entire sequence of elements, right in the middle in the best case, followed by splitting the remaining chunks, until there are enough chunks to keep every CPU core busy. Naturally, this strategy isn’t well suited for selecting elements from the beginning of the sequence to an element, with a condition incorporating all affected elements.

But for completeness, it is possible to do that in parallel, though it’s rather unlikely to have a benefit from that. You’d need a really large number of elements and a significant fraction has to be in the selection.

```
int[] values = selectedItems.parallelStream().mapToInt(Item::getValue).toArray();
Arrays.parallelPrefix(values, Integer::sum);
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(values, limitValue);
index = index < 0? -index-1: index+1;
listOfItems.subList(0, index).parallelStream()
// your actual heavy operation
```

Comment: It needs heavy calculations to get each value, so I want to parallelize them.

Comment: Important is `/* set value */`. `/* do something */` can be ignored.

Comment: More, `/* set value */` calculates the value and some other objects, and I want to keep them after counting values.

Comment: So `/* set value */` is applied to all elements anyway, regardless of the limit applied to subsequent operations? That’s actually easy to achieve, e.g. in the second example, just insert it between `.parallelStream()` and `.mapToInt(Item::getValue)`…