# Java Stream minimum with known bound

Tags: java, performance, collections, java-stream, minimum

I have a Stream of Lists of which I want to get the entry with the least elements. I could of course do something like

```
Stream<List<T>> s = ...
s.min((e1, e2) -> e1.size() - e2.size());
```

But in a case like this, we know a lower bound for the minimum, since the size is non-negative. Meaning the moment a List of size 0 is found, we could actually stop, instead of running through the rest of the list too.
Can this be achieved in a decent way with Java Streams?

I would imagine it looking something like this, giving a comparator and a function which tells us when the current minimum is a global one:

```
s.boundedMin(
    (e1, e2) -> e1.size() - e2.size(),
    e -> e.size() == 0
)
```

I can't think of a way to implement this.

Of course I could just use an Iterable and use a loop with break-statement to get this, I just wondered if streams could get me there too.

Edit:
To make it a bit clearer. The Stream *might* or *might not* contain Lists of size 0. My issue is that min() will run through the whole stream, even if it already found a list of size 0 (which is already as small as it can ever get). So, what I'm looking for is **an implementation of min which does not need to scan through the whole stream, by providing a lower bound for the minimum.**

Edit2:
An equivalent iterative solution without streams would be

```
List<List<T>> s = ...
List<T> min = null;
for (List<T> l : s) {
        if (min == null || min.size() > l.size())
            min = l;
        if (min.size() == 0) {
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate) might help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please elaborate it a bit more. Please provide your iterative solution so at least that gives us some impression on what you need to achive.

Comment: My first though was s.takeWhile(Predicate.not(Collection::isEmpty)).min(Comparator.comparing(Collection::size)); . Unfortunately it will not work, because 'takeWhile' method is not inclusive.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I edited my question, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: the problem is that you want a short-circuiting _conditional_ exit; streams were not made for this. are you forced to use a `Stream<List<T>>`? there are at least two issues here : 1) your Lists might not have a trivial `size` 2) the stream might be lazily computed - making your requirement entirely valid; but again _only_ if you are stuck with a `Stream<List<T>>`, otherwise you already know what to do...

Comment: @Eugene No I am not forced to use Streams in this scenario. I was initially using streams, and then thought of ways to improve performance. Replacing this with the looped approach gave me a speedup of factor 3.
But I was still curious whether or not this is possible to achieve using Streams. 

A lazily computed stream would be a valid usecase for such a requirement, but another one I could think of would be a scenario where you just want a close enough approximation of the minimum.

Comment: a close enough approximation to the minimum would be a job for `ceilingEntry` or the like...

Comment: (Aside)If I am not mistaken, the iterative solution and the one with the stream are not the same. In one you are accessing the `List` with a minimum value of size and in another just the size.

Comment: @Naman That was a mistake of my side when hastily adding the iterative solution, you're right of course. Edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the fun of it:

```
static <T> int size(Stream<List<T>> st) {

    class MinHolder implements Consumer<List<T>> {

        private int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        public void accept(List<T> l) {
            if (min > l.size()) {
                min = l.size();
            }
        }
    }

    MinHolder holder = new MinHolder();
    Spliterator<List<T>> sp = st.spliterator();

    int elements = 0;
    for (; sp.tryAdvance(holder) && holder.min > 0; ++elements) {

    }

    System.out.printf("took %s elements to find the min%n", elements);
    return holder.min;
}
```

And a few test cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<List<Integer>> st = Stream.of(List.of());
    System.out.println(size(st));

    st = Stream.empty();
    System.out.println(size(st));

    st = Stream.of(List.of(), List.of(1), List.of(1, 2), List.of(1, 2, 3));
    System.out.println(size(st));
}
```

If you are not forced to use a `Stream<List<T>>` then don't; this *conditional* breaking is not something Streams were designed for and would be considered an abuse by many.