# How to re-write `while(true)` in Java Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Can this Java code be re-written by Stream API?

```java
while (true) {
    ...
    if (isTrue()) break;
}

private boolean isTrue() {
    ...
```

Comment: Why do you need to? What's wrong with a loop? Do you actually have a stream of data elements?

Comment: where does stream come into picture here?

Comment: I have no need but I want to know whether it can.

Comment: A stream is not infinite.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson are you [sure](https://www.baeldung.com/java-inifinite-streams)?

Comment: I don't think that that's what Streams are for. Think of streams like an assembly line. The assembly line has a beginning (`myList.stream()`) and somewhere it has an end (`collect(Collectors.toList())`). This assembly line starts with empty boxes and at the first station someone puts a smartphone in each box. At the second station someone else checks the boxes if they all have a phone in it and removes the empty boxes (`filter()`) and at another station someone puts earplugs in the box... and so on.. Now your `while` loop does not actually fit in that image if you don't have a stream.

Comment: You could probably abuse streams to do it, with a suitable `map()` and `anyMatch()/allMatch()`. But why bother writing bad code?

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks, I hadn't seen that or had the need to reasearch it. Something new learned today :)

Comment: @blackeyedcenter take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate

Comment: Thank you for your all comments! They are useful for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is **horrible** code, there's **no reason ever to use this**. Streams are an additional tool to regular loops, they're not a replacement for `for` and especially `while` loops.

```
// If you use this code seriously somewhere, I will find you
IntStream.generate(() -> 0)
    .peek(i -> {
        // Any custom logic
        System.out.println(i);
    })
    .noneMatch(i -> isTrue());
```

The code generates zeroes infinitely, peeks in the stream to perform custom logic, then stops when `noneMatch` evaluates to `true`.

The above is equivalent to the code in the question, which can be written far more succinctly as

```
do {
    // custom logic
} while(!isTrue());
```

Comment: I feel so dirty.

Comment: Thank you! I confirmed this works as I intended.

Comment: @blackeyedcenter now you must make a [pinky swear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinky_swear) never to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace or rewrite while loop with Stream API. Stream API reads values from Stream. `while (true)` is not reading data from any stream. It is simply a infinite loop.