# Rewrite cycle with break to lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I had a cycle for counter:

```
List<Mt4Report> history = ...
int counter = 0;
for (Mt4Report item : history) {
    if (item.getProfit().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0) {
        counter++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

How I can write the same idea with lambda expression something `.findFirst().ifPresent` but withholding break statement?

Comment: i will say you have the clear version according to java 8

Comment: Why not filter the stream based on `item.getProfit().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZER) < 0` and then just call `count()`?

Comment: @ahoxha that's exactly what I did but Pavel requires that the stream terminates when the condition in the `filter` is false for which I have answered in context of Java 8

Comment: When you use streams, you don't tell them how to perform the task, but rather what task to perforn. I am not sure if the order is important, but if you want to find all items with profit less then zero, than you just filter the stream and call `count()`. On the other hand, if he is breaking the loop on the first non-zero item (which could omit other zero items later on the list), I don't understand the logic.

Comment: @ahoxha it may be a fail-fast logic for something where you expect all profits to be zero but even if one non zero item is encountered then simply break and return the number of zero items

Comment: @Shankha057, yes you're right, it might be something like that.

Answer (score 4):

With Java-9 and above, you can use `takeWhile` approach as :

```
int counter = (int) history.stream()
        .takeWhile(item -> item.getProfit().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0)
        .count();
```

For the Java-8 solution, you can look into a custom implementation of `takeWhile` provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate). On the other hand, a less efficient implementation with the use of `indexOf` could be to perform:

```
int count = history.stream()
        .filter(ite -> ite.getProfit().compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) >= 0)
        .findFirst()
        .map(history::indexOf)
        .orElse(history.size());
```

As Holger suggested to improve the above solution, you can make use of the `IntStream` with `findFirst`:

```
int count = IntStream.range(0, history.size())
                     .filter(ix -> history.get(ix).getProfit() .compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) >= 0)
                     .findFirst()
                     .orElse(history.size());
```

Comment: Yes, the good solution very compact and readable but it for 9 version my question was about version 8.

Comment: I think your java8 code is not correct, as @Pavel wants to find items with profit < 0, not >= 0.

Comment: @ahoxha It's just the logic reversed, notice the `indexOf` for the first non-fitting element as a result.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. @Pavel, I think Nama's java8 version is the one you are looking for.

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, history.size()) .filter(ix -> history.get(ix).getProfit() .compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) >= 0) .findFirst() .orElse(history.size());` avoids the second linear search through the list.

Answer (score 1):

As per Java 8 there is no direct solution for this problem, which is basically stopping a `Stream` using a `Predicate`.
In Java 9 you have the `takeWhile()` method but in Java 8, there is no such thing like that.
Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate)

Comment: No, this counting all compared case. My code counting only from 0 index and blamelessly cases.

Comment: @Pavel then you have to refer to the post in my answer where there are some hacks around this.