# Break or return from java 8 map reduce in functional interface

Tags: java, lambda, mapreduce, java-stream, functional-interface

I have a java 8 functional interface that accepts a list of validators that are applied on an object and returns the validation result. The validation results are accumulated in the reduce phase. The code as follows:

```
public interface LogicalTableValidator extends Function<LogicalTable, ValidationResult> {

    static LogicalTableValidator addAll(LogicalTableValidator... validators) {

        //  Need to break out of this validator stream, based on the criticality of a particular validation error
        return logicalTable -> Arrays.stream(validators).map(v -> v.apply(logicalTable))
                .reduce(new ValidationResult(logicalTable.getUid()), (validationResult, currentResult) -> {
                    validationResult.addValidationMessages(currentResult.getValidationMessages());
                    return validationResult;
                });

    }

}
```

This validation logic gets called from here

```
LogicalTableValidator logicalTableValidators = LogicalTableValidator.addAll(getValidators());
List<ValidationResult> ltValidationResults = logicalTables.stream()
                                                          .parallel()
                                                          .map(logicalTableValidators)
                                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The problem I am facing is that, I am not able to break from the validation logic conditionally. This will be the case when I am applying the validators on the logicalObject, if the validation fails with a critical error, I dont need to run rest of the validators. Instead I need to stop the validation process right there.

A work around would be not to use lambda expression for validation and use the following code instead.

```
        return new LogicalTableValidator() {

            @Override
            public ValidationResult apply(LogicalTable t) {
                ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult(t.getUid());
                for (LogicalTableValidator validator : validators) {
                    ValidationResult currentResult = validator.apply(t);
                    List<ValidationMessage> messages = currentResult.getValidationMessages();
                    Boolean exit = false;
                    for (ValidationMessage message : messages) {
                        if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(message.getSeverity(),  "1")) {
                            exit = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    result.addValidationMessages(currentResult.getValidationMessages());
                    if (exit) break;
                }
                return result;
            }

        };
```

It seems, not using lambda expression in functional interface, defeats the purpose of using functional interface, but I couldn't figure out a way to conditionally break out of the validation loop. Is there any alternative I can use? Should this code be structured in a different way?

Comment: Why you don't use filter()?

Comment: filter() would still still iterate through all the objects checking for filter condition. I want to break out of the loop if and when a critical error is encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below. In `peek` it collect `ValidationMessages`. In `filter` and `findFirst` it stop after first error message. It is replacement for `takeWhile` that was mentioned in comments, you can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43779847/11733759).

```java
public interface LogicalTableValidator extends Function<LogicalTable, ValidationResult> {

    static LogicalTableValidator addAll(LogicalTableValidator... validators) {

        logicalTable -> {
            ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult(logicalTable.getUid());
            Arrays.stream(validators).map(v -> v.apply(logicalTable))
                    .peek(currentResult -> result.addValidationMessages(currentResult.getValidationMessages()))
                    .filter(currentResult -> currentResult.getValidationMessages().stream()
                            .filter(message -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(message.getSeverity(), "1"))
                            .count() > 0)
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(null);
            return result;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct things: 1. breaking `logicalTables` stream and 2. breaking `validators` stream.

For `logicalTables`, your stream is parallel and even if the break was possible you would obtain potentially different results.

For `validators` stream, `Stream.takeWhile` seems to be the closest to pure stream-based solution. Unfortunately, it is in JDK since Java 9 and moreover it doesn't comprise invalid `ValidationResult` into resulting stream. Alternatives might exist in external libraries though the imperative code seems to me as simplest and readable enough at this moment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am only looking breaking out of validator stream based on the criticality of the validation error. I did find java 9 Stream.takeWhile, but unfortunately we are in java 8, and not in a position to move to java 9 anytime soon.