# How to combine logic using Java 8 streams to add to a list based on list size condition

Tags: java, java-stream

Is it possible to combine below using Java 8 streams that if there is some value for “getCount()” then keep on adding elements to same list to till size of the list is more than getCount().

```
List<RequestObject> li = results().map(req -> new RequestObject(req())).collect(Collectors.toList());

if(Objects.nonNull(getCount())){
    while(li.size() <= getCount()) {
        li.addAll(li);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes correct. I edited the post. Many thanks @Andreas

Comment: You do know that you keep doubling the list in size, right? E.g. if the list initially has 3 values, and `getCount()` returns `6`, then you end up with a list with 12 values, i.e. each initial value will now appear 4 times each.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I need to create a payload having list's size greater than or less than based on count value.

Comment: adding same list again and again `li.addAll(li);`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use Java 9, it provides `dropWhile(predicate)` and `takeWhile(predicate)` for streams.

```
int count = 0;
List<RequestObject> li = results()
                         .map(mapping)
                         .takeWhile(obj -> {count++ <= getCount()});
```

**EDIT**: in case of Java 8 you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate)

Comment: Sadly, we are still on Java 8. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Abhinav and also I believe there are some 3rd party tools for that. Take a look at this article http://dubravsky.com/b/how-to-use-dropwhile-and-takewhile-in-java-8

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
        List<Integer> list = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < getCount(), i -> i+1)
                .map(b -> getNext()).boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(list);


        public static int getCount() {
           return 10;
        }
        k = 0;

        public static int getNext() {
          k += 10;
          return k;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with create new collection based on `li`:

```java
List<RequestObject> collect = IntStream.range(0, getCount())
        .mapToObj(i -> li.get(i % li.size()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

#### UPDATE

I assumed that what you want can be shown on this example (where `getCount()` is `count`):

```java
List<String> li = new ArrayList<>(List.of("a", "b", "c"));
int count = 2;
List<String> collect = IntStream.range(0, count)
        .mapToObj(i -> li.get(i % li.size()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then you get:

```
[a, b]
```

and for example  `count = 10`:

```
[a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c, a]
```

Comment: list size remains same as initial size. It does not adds in the list

Comment: @Abhinav try now