# Collect a stream after an objects attribute exceeds a certain threshold

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream, skip

Assume I have a list of custom objects `MaDate` with a field `temp` of type `int`. I want to use streams to get all items after the first hits a certain threshold `MaDate.temp >= 10` .

```
class MaDate {
    int temp;
    // some other fields
    MaDate(int temp){
       this.temp = temp;
    }
    int getTemp(){
        return temp;
    }
}
```

And

```
 List<MaDate> myList = new ArrayList<>();
 myList.add(new MaDate(3));
 myList.add(new MaDate(7));
 myList.add(new MaDate(8));
 myList.add(new MaDate(4));
 myList.add(new MaDate(10));
 myList.add(new MaDate(3));
 myList.add(new MaDate(9));
```

Ideally the result list should contain the last 3 elements having `temp` values [10,3,9].

I can not use `filter`

```
myList.stream().filter(m -> m.getTemp() >= 10)...
```

because this would eliminate every object with value under 10. And I can not also use `skip`

```
myList.stream().skip(4)...
```

because I do not know the index beforehand. I can not use

```
findFirst(m -> m.getTemp() >= 10)
```

because I need all objects after the treshold was reached once regardles which values the objects have after that.

Can I combine those above somehow to get what I want or write my own method to put in `skip` or `filter`

```
 myList.stream().skip(**as long as treshold not met**)
```

or

```
 myList.stream().filter(**all elements after first element value above 10**)
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you can use [`Stream#dropWhile(Predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)):

> Returns, if this stream is ordered, a stream consisting of the remaining elements of this stream after dropping the longest prefix of elements that match the given predicate. Otherwise returns, if this stream is unordered, a stream consisting of the remaining elements of this stream after dropping a subset of elements that match the given predicate.

Example:

```java
List<MaDate> originalList = ...;
List<MaDate> newList = originalList.stream()
        .dropWhile(m -> m.getTemp() < 10)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that `dropWhile` was added in Java 9. This Q&A shows a workaround if you're using Java 8: [Limit a stream by a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate).

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I need.