# Is first <T> related to the Optional<T>? How to understand what the first <T> and Optional<T> is doing?

Tags: java, generics

```
public static <T> Optional<T> of(<T> value) {
    return new Optional<> value 
}
```

Is first `<T>` related to the `Optional<T>`? How to understand what first `<T>` and `Optional<T>` is doing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate.  If you try to find the first element of a stream but there are no elements - what is the result nothing or the first element - hence optional.

Comment: See [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) in the Java tutorial.