# Getting two different outputs from a Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am testing out the new `Stream` [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) in java-8 and want to check the outcome of 10000 random coinflips. So far I have:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random r = new Random();
        IntStream randomStream = r.ints(10000,0, 2);

        System.out.println("Heads: " + randomStream.filter(x -> x==1).count());
        System.out.println("Tails: " + randomStream.filter(x -> x==0).count());
    }
```

but this throws the exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
```

I understand why this is happenning but how can i print the count for heads and tails if I can only use the stream once?

Comment: I think this problem is addressed (and hopefully solved) on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803058/java-8-stream-getting-head-and-tail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This first solution is relying on the fact that counting the number of heads and tails of 10 000 coinflips follows a binomial law.

For this particular use case, you can use the [`summaryStatistics`](http://download.java.net/lambda/b85/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics%28%29) method.

```
Random r = new Random();
IntStream randomStream = r.ints(10000,0, 2);
IntSummaryStatistics stats =  randomStream.summaryStatistics();
System.out.println("Heads: "+ stats.getSum());
System.out.println("Tails: "+(stats.getCount()-stats.getSum()));
```

---

Otherwise you can use the [`collect`](http://download.java.net/lambda/b78/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect%28java.util.function.Supplier,%20java.util.function.BiConsumer,%20java.util.function.BiConsumer%29) operation to create a map which will map each possible result with its number of occurences in the stream.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = randomStream
                            .collect(HashMap::new, 
                                     (m, key) -> m.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum), 
                                     Map::putAll);
System.out.println(map); //{0=4976, 1=5024}
```

The advantage of the last solution is that this works for any bounds you give for the random integers you want to generate.

Example:

```
IntStream randomStream = r.ints(10000,0, 5);
....
map => {0=1991, 1=1961, 2=2048, 3=1985, 4=2015}
```

Comment: could i ask merge is what method?

Answer (score 5):

While all other answers are correct, they are formulated a bit cumbersome.

`Map<Integer, Long>`, maps the flipped coin to a count.

```
Map<Integer, Long> coinCount = new Random().ints(10000, 0, 2)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()));
```

This will first create the `IntStream`, then box them to an `Stream<Integer>`, as you will be storing them in their boxed version anyhow in this example. And lastly collect them with a `groupingBy` function on the identity `i -> i`, which gives you a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`, which is not what you want, hence you replace the `List<Integer>` with the operation `Collectors.counting()` on it, such that the `List<Integer>` becomes a `Long`, hence resulting in a `Map<Integer, Long>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect several results in a single iteration, if you want to get two outputs. In your case, it might look as follows:

```
Random r = new Random();
IntStream randomStream = r.ints(10000,0, 2);

int[] counts = randomStream.collect(
    () -> new int[] { 0, 0 }, // supplier
    (a, v) -> a[v]++, // accumulator
    (l, r) -> { l[0] += r[0]; l[1] += r[1]; }); // combiner

System.out.println("Heads: " + counts[0]);
System.out.println("Tails: " + counts[1]);
```