# can I get filtered list as a parameter to filter predicate in java 8?

Tags: filter, java-8

I am trying to TDD the prime factors Kata of uncle Bob in java 8 style.
I got the code working, and I want to add an improvment for checking if a number is prime by looking only at previous prime numbers and not all numbers.

```
public class PrimeFactorsGenerator {

    public static List<Integer> generate(int number) {
        return createListOfNumberUntil(number).stream().
            filter(x -> isDivided(number, x)).
            filter(x -> isPrime(x)).
            collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(Integer t) {
        for (int i = 2; i < t; i++) {
            if(isDivided(t, i)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static List<Integer> createListOfNumberUntil(int number) {
        List<Integer> $ = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
            $.add(i);
        }
        return $;
    }

    private static boolean isDivided(int num, int i) {
        return num % i == 0;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get the filtered list as a parameter to the `isPrime` method?

Comment: Seems like you want to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19803058/2711488    Note that it doesn’t make sense to create an `ArrayList` of numbers just to call `stream()` on it afterwards. Use `IntStream.iterate(firstValue, i -> i + 1)`.

Comment: Or you could use `IntStream.range(from, to)` if you know the upper bound. It's probably easier to split a range than a stream from `iterate()` since the function passed to `iterate()` must be called repeatedly to generate the values, whereas the values in `range` are virtual.