# How to return object instead of stream using peek or anyMatch

Tags: java, lambda

I have this piece of code:

```
boolean anyMatch = ifxStopChkInqRs.getBankSvcRs().stream().anyMatch(
  b -> b.getStopChkInqRs().stream().anyMatch(
    i -> i.getStopChkRec().stream()
      .filter(d -> d.getStopChkInfo().getDesc().equals("D"))
      .findFirst()
      .isPresent()));
```

This returns a true/false value correctly, and quits at the first object it finds if any.

But, how can I return the object itself, which in this case would be of type `StopChkRec` - the `i` object? I changed both `anyMatch` to `peek` and a added a  `get()` in front of `findFirst()`, but that returned a stream at the highest level - `Stream<BankSvcRs>` - which beats the whole search purpose of course.

Any help and/or a re-approach to re-constructing this lambda expression is welcome.

Comment: have you tried `filter` instead of `anyMatch`?

Comment: `filter` wouldn't fit in place of `anyMatch` in my case I think - I tried it but it makes the entire expression RED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
    Optional<StopChkRecType> findFirst = ifxStopChkInqRs.getBankSvcRs()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(b -> b.getStopChkInqRs().stream())
        .flatMap(i -> i.getStopChkRec().stream())
        .filter(d -> d.getStopChkInfo().getDesc().equals("D"))
        .findFirst();
```

Answer inspired by @ykaganovich who put me on the right track with `flatMap`, but also at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828710/iterating-through-nested-collections-to-find-first-sub-sub-sub-element-matching) link which explains how to go deep and come out clean.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? (untested)

```
ifxStopChkInqRs.getBankSvcRs().stream().flatMap(b -> b.getStopChkInqRs())
  .filter(i -> i != null)
  .flatMap(i -> i.getStopChkRec())
    .filter(d -> (d != null && d.getStopChkInfo().getDesc().equals("D")))
    .findFirst()
```

I don't know where you need to filter out nulls, and if you can use findAny() instead of findFirst()

Comment: I tested your expression but it wouldn't even pass syntax validation. Nulls are okay, for I may be looking for what's not there. I thought Optional would help in this regard. Why the `flatMap`? I will read on it a little.